# What is the difference between (int) -1 and (-1) in C?

Tags: c

I am wondering if the following are the same:

```
#define IDEFAULT (-1)
```

and

```
#define IDEFAULT (int) -1
```

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because I'm not seeing a lot of value in questions comparing and contrasting the limitless combinations of possible syntax errors.

Comment: What is the purpose of this? Are you learning by trial and error?

Comment: ooops i forgot the # at the beginning! Please re-open.

Comment: Hi @imageguy and welcome to the site! :) Even if you prepend `#`, and/or append `;`, this will still lead to a syntax error. Try it out online in [Wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/rfGxn6OM16Bs2fhn), if you like. :)

Comment: edited the second time, missed the variable name

Comment: Yes, both are the same. `-1` has type of `int` anyway. However there might be some tricky usages. For example if you have a function named `foo`, then `foo IDEFAULT;` will result in a legal call `foo(-1);`, in the first case, but illegal `foo (int) -1;` thingy in the second case.

Comment: The `(-1)` form is conventional.  `(int)-1` is... strange.  Under most circumstances they'll behave identically.  It's probably possible to contrive an obscure circumstance under which the second one would do something unexpected.  I'd stick with the `(-1)` form.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's unlikely to be useful to future readers.

Comment: These two are the same. They define a macro called `IDEFAULT` with the value `-1`.

If you had done instead:

`#define IDEFAULT -1`
then it would've been slightly different; if someone had written:

`5 IDEFAULT`
with the above definition, it would be `4`. With your two definitions, it would be a syntax error (which in this case would be good).

Answer (score 5):

> I am wondering if the following are the same :

Both are the same, in the sense that they produce a **syntax error**.

It seems that you are trying to use a **Macro in C**, and for that the correct syntax is:

```
#define macro-name char-sequence
```

so I would write for example:

```
#define myMacro -1
```

where `myMacro` is going to be equal to -1. If I surround -1 with parentheses, it won't make a difference. Read more about it in [Why use Macros in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1358232/why-use-macros-in-c)

---

PS: The syntax errors however, are not identical:

```
main.c:3:9: error: expected declaration specifiers or '...' before '-' token
    3 | define (-1)
      |         ^
```

and

```
main.c:3:1: warning: return type defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]
    3 | define (int) -1
      | ^~~~~~
main.c: In function 'define':
main.c:3:14: error: expected declaration specifiers before '-' token
    3 | define (int) -1
      |              ^
main.c:3:9: error: parameter name omitted
    3 | define (int) -1
      |         ^~~
main.c:8: error: expected '{' at end of input
    8 | }
      |
```