# Case sensitive string comparison in C++

Tags: c++, string

Can anyone pls let me know the exact c++ code of case sensitive comparison function of string class?

Comment: @Aman Saleem: What is wrong with the == operator?

Comment: case sensitive or case insensitive?

Comment: Please give your questions more descriptive titles -- "C++ Object Oriented Programming" is way too generic. I've gone in and done this one for you.

Comment: String comparison is case sensitive by default. Just use `operator==` for `std::string`.

Comment: Kirill, can u pls let me the code?

Comment: What's wrong with mine, dumbcoder or Arjit's examples?

Comment: If you need an answer to this question (or think the examples provided by the others are not "detailed" enough) to get you work done I don't think c++ is a very good choice (you should even doubt if you should be programming). If you took a book about C++ this will be covered in the very first parts of the book (since strings are used very often).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
std::string str1("A new String");
std::string str2("a new STring");
if(str1.compare(str2) == 0)
    std::cout<<"Equal";     // str1("A new String") str2("A new String");
else 
    std::cout<<"unEqual";   //str1("A new String") str2("a new STring")
```

compare() returns an integral value rather than a boolean value. Return value has the following meaning: 0 means equal, a value less than zero means less than, and a value greater than zero means greater than

Comment: Can u pls give the code in output of that the str1 is equal to str2 if both strings are equal & give the output that str1 is not equal to str2 if both the string are not equal?

Comment: Why would you use compare rather than `operator==` ?

Answer (score 5):

How about?

```
std::string str1, str2;
/* do stuff to str1 and str2 */
if (str1 == str2) { /* do something */ }
```

Or

```
if (str1.compare(str2) == 0) { /* the strings are the same */ }
```

Answer (score 2):

== is overloaded for string comparison in C++ AFAIK (unlike in Java, where u have to use myString.equals(..))

If you want to ignore case when comparing, just convert both strings to upper or lower case as explained here: [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main ()
{
  string str1 ("green apple");
  string str2 ("red apple");

  if (str1.compare(str2) != 0)
    cout << str1 << " is not " << str2 << "\n";

  if (str1.compare(6,5,"apple") == 0)
    cout << "still, " << str1 << " is an apple\n";

  if (str2.compare(str2.size()-5,5,"apple") == 0)
    cout << "and " << str2 << " is also an apple\n";

  if (str1.compare(6,5,str2,4,5) == 0)
    cout << "therefore, both are apples\n";

  return 0;
}
```

I got it from http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/compare/

Hope google work !!

But use == operator like 
s1 == s2 would also work good