# How can I stream hexadecimal numbers with A-F (rather than a-f)?

Tags: c++, hex, iostream, iomanip

Is it possible to make `ostream` output hexadecimal numbers with characters `A-F` and not `a-f`?

```
int x = 0xABC;
std::cout << std::hex << x << std::endl;
```

This outputs `abc` whereas I would prefer to see `ABC`.

Comment: Could the downvoter of this question please be so kind as to explain to me what is so criminal about this question? As a matter of fact, I had opened MSDN for 'hex' in hopes to find the answer, but I didn't. So what's wrong with this question?

Comment: Don't know, but here's a upvote to counter it. I love doing that because it's fair (especially to those who have a genuine question - SO is meant to be for _all_ levels of developer, not just obnoxious know-it-alls like me) but mostly because it annoys the drive-by downvoters who can't even be bothered to leave a comment so that a question can be improved. Of course, they may well downvote my answer in retribution but it's not like I'm short of rep :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo: my feeling about retaliatory downvotes is that anyone likely to get involved in such nonsense has less than half my rep, so I'm going to win that one. Since I have less than half your rep, you can outlast twice as many...

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, you can use `std::uppercase`, which affects floating point and hexadecimal integer output:

```
std::cout << std::hex << std::uppercase << x << std::endl;
```

as in the following complete program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>

int main (void) {
    int x = 314159;
    std::cout << std::hex << x << " " << std::uppercase << x << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs:

```
4cb2f 4CB2F
```

Comment: Will this modifier affect hex numbers only, or will it affect strings as well?

Comment: Hex numbers and exponents in scientific notation. If you want to do strings, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case

Answer (score 1):

In C++20 you'll be able to use [`std::format`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/format) to do this:

```cpp
std::cout << std::format("{:X}\n", 0xABC);
```

Output:

```
ABC
```

In the meantime you can use [the {fmt} library](https://github.com/fmtlib/fmt), `std::format` is based on. {fmt} also provides the `print` function that makes this even easier and more efficient ([godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/Kdj7oW)):

```
fmt::print("{:X}\n", 0xABC);
```

**Disclaimer**: I'm the author of {fmt} and C++20 `std::format`.