# c++ toupper - standard function?

Tags: c++, cross-platform, standard-library, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

Hi,
I need a portable function to convert string in c++ to upper case. I'm now using toupper( char); function. Is it a standard function? If not, what it's the correct way to do it across platforms? Btw, is there any web / wiki where I can list all c++ standard functions? Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, `toupper` is declared in the `cctype` header. You can transform a string with an algorithm:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <cctype>

int main()
{
    std::string str("hello there");
    std::cout << str << '\n';

    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), std::toupper);
    std::cout << str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: you'll need the scope resolution operator

Comment: Is there any recommendation when to use toupper(char) and when toupper(char, locale)?

Answer (score 1):

For the latter question, there's http://www.cplusplus.com/.

Answer (score 0):

Hi in our project we use boost/algorithm/string to_upper function project for windows and linux