# error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol due to helper library

Tags: c++, lnk2019

I think the issue is with a function `ConvertToUpperCase` included in a helper library used in my CS course. I am trying to write something for my experiment but I learned with the helper library - so I don't know what to do without it.

The full error error:

> LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "class std::basic_string,class std::allocator > __cdecl ConvertToUpperCase(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?ConvertToUpperCase@@YA?AV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@V12@@Z) referenced in function "public: bool __thiscall Lexicon::containsPrefix(class std::basic_string,class std::allocator >)" (?containsPrefix@Lexicon@@QAE_NV?$basic_string@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@V?$allocator@D@2@@std@@@Z)

The function is included in `strutils.h`  and explained [here](http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/documentation/strutils_8h.html)

Sample code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <fstream>
#include "genlib.h"
#include "strutils.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "set.h"
#include "lexicon.h"

using namespace std;

/* Function: AddWord1
* -----------------
* This function prompts the user for a code and then
* coverts entry to upper case and adds this word to the code list passed in.
*/
void AddWord1(Lexicon & lex)
{
    cout << "Please enter activity code to add: ";
    string word = ConvertToUpperCase(GetLine()); //may need to remove for code
    lex.add(word);
    cout << word << " added to code list." << endl;
}
```

Clarification:

- yes, this was working code in 2009 and 2010 - so it was implemented.
- the library was a .lib and I am now using the [sourceForge version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/progabstrlib/).
- VS 2008, it last was working from a VS2005 compile, I have tried VS2005 and VS2011BETA but still have errors.
- I am trying to make sure the appropriate cpp files are added to the project; I think they are. My genlib.cpp is dated 2011 and is different than the github.com/b33tr00t/cs106lib version which is for Linux users, so it makes sense that there are some differences.

Comment: Did you ever implement it (i.e. give the function a body)?

Comment: did the prof give you the source code or the compiled library? which platform are you on? whats the compiler your are using?

Comment: interesting I found this https://github.com/b33tr00t/cs106lib, still make sure you've add the appropriate cpp files to your project and its being compiled assuming you are on windows using VS.

Comment: I will edit my post to clarify

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There should be a library containing the compiled code as well as the header that you have. You need to add that library (a .lib or .obj file) to your project - specifically you need to include it in the linker settings.

If you don't have that then you might have one or more C++ source files defining those functions - you could add those to the project.

If you have none of those then you have a problem, I'm afraid.

Comment: I have the C++ source files in the same folder as the project, they are not added since they produce a bunch or compiler errors.

Comment: There are 2 linker errors repeated, these are LNK2019(ConvertToUpperCase; IntegerToString; a Template issue; and Error), LNK 2001(ConvertToUpperCase; IntegerToString; and Error), and LNK2019 (GetLine; GetInteger; and template issues) I dove into the ConvertToUpperCase, checking the source file and changed the source file from .c to a .cpp version. Changing the source file brought a bunch of new compiler errors specific to the new source files.

Comment: after updating the source files the linker errors are gone - there a re new errors relating to one of the files so I will open a new question to address those

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have access to that library anymore (since you may no longer be in the class), you can write your own `ConvertToUpperCase` function using one of the techniques from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case).

Comment: I have access to the library - 1) the TA from last qtr is working with me by email http://www.stanford.edu/class/cs106x/handouts/06-Library-Reference.pdf, 2) the library contents are posted to sourceForge, 3) the library is posted online. I'd like to move away from using the .lib file and use the source files - this handout explains http://www.keithschwarz.com/cs106l/spring2009/handouts/020_Writing_Without_Genlib.pdf Also, I wrote a function to replace convertToUpperCase but then looked at the source file and realized  it was the same function using toupper()

Comment: after updating the source files the linker errors are gone - there a re new errors relating to one of the files so I will open a new question to address those