# function for converting string case?

Tags: c++, string

is there a single function in c++ that converts strings from lowercase to uppercase and vice versa? I need to compare two strings case insensitive and I can only convert one of the strings and the other needs to be intact.

Comment: do you mean `std::string` or a `char *` string?

Comment: 10 characters is not "a lot of work to convert".

Comment: @Rapptz He unrolls the loop.

Comment: @SingerOfTheFall I mean std:string

Comment: @Rapptz I meant there are 10 slots in my custom structured array and each one have a string slot. But I need to compare the user inputted strings with the strings without going through a loop.

Comment: @AlokSave  I already looked at it, and it is not very helpful.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju then none of the answers here are either.

Comment: It answers the question that is conveyed through your post. Whether you want to ask what is really being conveyed through the question is for you to ponder upon and improve on.

Comment: It sounds like you need to do a case insensitive comparison rather than converting a string and then comparing.

Comment: @PeterWood yes, you are right, a case insensitive comparison.

Comment: Possible duplicate: [Case insensitive string comparison in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/q/11635/1084416)

Comment: As Peter's comment implies, uppercasing and then comparing is not in general the same as doing a case insensitive comparison. It probably suffices for your use case since this appears to be some school assignment, but I think it's worth pointing out.

Comment: @PeterWood I saw this but I am worried if my teacher doesnt have the boost library, the code wont work in his compiler.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes the thing I am worried about is if my teacher doesnt have the boost libraries the code wont work, and I cant talk to him in person either as this is an online class :(

Comment: The first answer uses boost, the other answers don't.

Comment: See also [Herb Sutter](http://www.gotw.ca/gotw/029.htm)

Comment: @PeterWood I am trying    if(strcasecmp(books[i].bookTitle,titleFind)==0)    but doesnt work

Comment: @PeterWood I tried    <assert>     too,but it says could not convert

Comment: Read the whole article. The asserts are for example to show what the solution must be able to produce. It's not what you need to do. It is in the header `<cassert>` if you really want it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) or [`std::tolower`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower), in combination with <strike>`std::for_each`</strike> [`std::transform`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform).

```
#include <cctype>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
  std::string s = "Hello, World!";
  std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), [](char c) {return std::toupper(c);});
  std::cout << s << "\n";
}
```

**Edit**

> I need to compare two strings case insensitive and I can only convert one of the strings and the other needs to be intact.

You can define a function that performs a case-insensitive comparison of two characters, then use it with [`std::equal`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/equal):

```
bool case_insensitive_comp(char lhs, char rhs)
{
  return std::toupper(lhs) == std::toupper(rhs);
}

int main()
{
  std::string s1 = ....;
  std::string s2 = ....;
  bool match = std::equal(s1.begin(), s1.end(), s2.begin(), case_insensitive_comp); 
}
```

You might have to check that the length of the strings is the same before the call to `std::equal`.

Answer (score 1):

Could use [std::transform](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) with [std::toupper](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) or [std::tolower](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)

```
std::string s("hello, world!");
std::transform(s.begin(), s.end(), s.begin(), (int (*)(int))std::toupper);
```

Comment: what are s.begin(),s.end(). s.begin()?

Comment: add more code, it's string

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju: If you are asking that question, it is pretty much clear that you did not read the marked duplicate and if you didn't how can you say it is not helpful?

Comment: @billz it is actually a handful of strings which I have to compare with the string user inputs.

Comment: @AlokSave I can not use a function that the teacher did not use in class, it is for a project.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju can you make your question more clearer?

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju if you have such constraints you should specify it clearly in the question. Otherwise you are unlikely to get answers that are useful to your very specific domain.

Comment: @billz I can only convert one of the strings to either upper or lower completely and compare it with the other string that is inside a 10 character long structured array.

Comment: @MokammelHossainSanju update your question with `EDIT:` section, show your real question

Comment: @billz a case insensitive comparison to be clear.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

- `std::tolower`<sup>[click](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/tolower)</sup> and `std::toupper` <sup>[click](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper)</sup> with `std::transform`<sup>[click](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform)</sup>
- Boost, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case)
- Simply iterate through the string, as you suggested in the question. To convert *every* character in the string, you will *have to* iterate through it, anway.