# Change string element value in vector

Tags: c++

I'm working on right now  with `string` in `vector` . And i got my self in dead end . I've manipulate with `vector<int>` elements, and understand how to work with them ! I know how to work with `string` ! But i can't get thru the part where i need to change string element value in vector .I mean i don't know what to do in `loop` with "do something". So to be short i give the task on witch i work right now.

**Read a sequence of words from `cin` and store values in `vector`.After you've read all words,process the `vector` and change each word to uppercase**

Here what I've got so far

```
int main ()  
{
    vector<string> words;    //Container for all input word
    string inp;              //inp variable will process all input 

    while (cin>>inp)         //read
       words.push_back(inp); //Storing words 

    //Processing vector to make all word Uppercase
    for (int i = 0; i <words.size(); ++i)
     //do something

         words[i]=toupper(i);
    for (auto &e : words)    //for each element in vector 
     //do something

     cout<<e;

    keep_window_open("~");
    return 0;
}
```

This first `for` statement is not right i try access `vector` elements and change words to upper but it did't work for me its just sample
I've try many ways to access the `vector` element but when trying to use `string` member functions `toupper()` on `vector` i'm getting messy with code and logical mistakes!
Thanks For your time . 
Sorry for mistakes i made in spelling words

Comment: `toupper` only works on single characters. You might try combining it with `std::transform`.

Comment: `toupper` work with whole `string` in rangebase `for` statement.

Comment: Applying `toupper` to the *index* surely won't give anything useful.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

Comment: @StuartGolodetz Didnt find anything usefull out there !

Comment: @AlexGreat: The link was based on the thought that your underlying problem seems to be how to convert elements of the vector (strings) to uppercase. Put another way, `words[i]` is a string, and you can do anything to it that you would do to any other string. If you know how to make a string uppercase, you can make `words[i]` uppercase.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
for (auto& word: words)
  for (auto& letter: word)
    letter = std::toupper(letter);
```

Comment: THANK YOU ! that what i need . OMG itslook so  simple

Comment: There's no need to manually iterate through each `char` when you have ranged loops - By far this is the best solution!

Answer (score 2):

This can be fixed by using the `std::transform` Standard algorithm to iterate through the characters of the words. You can also use `std::for_each` instead of the manual loop.

```
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>
#include <vector>

int main()  
{
    std::vector<std::string> words;
    std::string inp;

    while (std::cin >> inp)
       words.push_back(inp);

    std::for_each(words.begin(), words.end(), [] (std::string& word)
    {
        std::transform(
            word.begin(),
            word.end(), 
            word.begin(), (int (&)(int)) std::toupper
        );
    })

    for (auto &e : words)
        std::cout << e << std::endl;
}
```

[And here is a demo.](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=a14eabed7aaa8a04b370be9165118130-41475e255c735859f2b181fd0d057a6f)

Comment: Not working out ! std has no member toupper ! and also got 8 errors in that code all of them about transform function!

Comment: @AlexGreat Include the header `<cctype>` and use my latest update.

Comment: `Error 3 error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'int' to 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>'

Comment: Error 2 error C2664: 'int (int)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from 'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>' to 'int'

Comment: @AlexGreat Okay, please use my newest update. I provided the entire new program.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this in the first for loop:

```
string w = words.at(i);
std::transform(w.begin(), w.end(), w.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Comment: it helps ! but it uppercase first index element. I need uppercase all chars in `vector`