# std::transform producing strange output

Tags: c++, c++11, stl

Today i was playing around with some standard Library      functions.. and found this weird output from std::transform() and std::back_inserter whenever the container am using(in this case vector) has more than 2 elements in it.I don't   understand this kind of behavior can anyone there help me...

```
#include<iostream>  
#include<algorithm>  
#include<vector>  
using namespace std;  

/* this version of change works fine for me when i store the incoming value into a   
   static variable  
int change(int n){  
 static int m=n;
 return m * m;  
}*/  

int change(int n){  
return n*n;  
}  

int main(){  
 vector<int> v2(3,3),  
            v1;  

 transform(v2.begin(),v2.end(),back_inserter(v2),change);  

 for(auto v: v2)  
  {   
    cout << v <<"  ";  // prints out a strange random 5th value in v2.  

  }  
 return 0;  
}
```

Comment: You generally aren't allowed to modify a container or invalidate iterators during the execution of an algorithm when that container is used as an input to the algorithm.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19200528/is-it-safe-for-the-input-iterator-and-output-iterator-in-stdtransform-to-be-fr

Comment: possible duplicate of [Iterator invalidation rules](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6438086/iterator-invalidation-rules)

Comment: Please avoid long lines in code-blocks. Not everyone looks at these pages with maximized browsers on desktops featuring extra-wide monitors.

Comment: @JaredHoberock thanks but why is it only the 5th element

Comment: @user3104126 Your code has undefined behavior, so it's pointless to speculate why you're observing a particular behavior.

Comment: BTW: [UB has a time-machine](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24527401), so due to the program encountering it on any possible execution, the program has undefined behavior right from the start.

Comment: @user3104126 probably a wizard did it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most likely cause is that the storage for the `vector` is being reallocated when you `push_back` elements into it (that's what assigning to the `back_insert_iterator` results in). This invalidates the `begin` and `end` iterators passed to `transform`, and subsequent assignments result in undefined behavior.

Your problem can be solved if you `reserve()` enough room in the `vector` before the call to `transform`

```
vector<int> v2(3,3);

v2.reserve(v2.size() * 2);
transform(v2.begin(),v2.end(),back_inserter(v2),change);
```

This produces the desired output.

> 3  3  3  9  9  9

[Live demo](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/6d950fb292c12a65)

Comment: thanks that worked....but the function works when i store the value of the incoming iterator into a static variable and return it..

Comment: @user3104126 It's still undefined behavior because `transform` is dereferencing invalid iterators once the `vector` resizes for the first time. It appears to work because by making `m` `static` within `change`, you initialize it *once* with the argument passed to `change` the very first time, and then keep returning the square of that value. So you're never using the invalid values being passed to `change` after the first call. Try adding `v2[0] = 1;` to the `static` version, and you'll see that all the new elements being added are `1`, and do not depend on the remaining `vector` elements.

Comment: thanks very much... well well on point am not using the invalid values passed to the function... thanks once again.