# How to convert large bitsets ie bitset<256> into hexadecimal in C++?

Tags: c++, binary, hex, bitset

I have a large bitset<256> that I want to convert to hexadecimal but common solutions of to_ulong() and to_ullong() throws overflow error.

```
        bitset<256> bitresult = to_bitset(hexToBinary(x2)) ^ to_bitset(hexToBinary(random[i-1]));
            stringstream res;

            bitset<64> b1;
            bitset<64> b2;
            bitset<64> b3;
            bitset<64> b4;

            for (int i1=0; i1<64; i1++)
            b1[i1]=bitresult[i1];
            for (int i1=0; i1<64; i1++)
            b2[i1]=bitresult[i1+64];
            for (int i1=0; i1<64; i1++)
            b3[i1]=bitresult[i1+128];
            for (int i1=0; i1<64; i1++)
            b4[i1]=bitresult[i1+192];

            res<< hex << b1.to_ullong();
            res<< hex << b2.to_ullong();
            res<< hex << b3.to_ullong();
            res<< hex << b4.to_ullong();
            string hashresult = res.str();
            cout << hashresult <<endl;
                 return sha256(hashresult);
```

However I am having issues returning them back to Hexadecimal, due to the large size, to.ullong() throws overflow error. The code above is my attempt but for me seems very flawed, is there a better solution to this ?

Comment: I've not personally had the need, but it looks like `bitset` has [built-in](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset) support for `hash`.

Comment: `std::bitset` is rather old, dont be surprised if it doesnt come with all bells and whistles you'd like to have. If you are commited to `std::bitset` imho your approach looks ok

Comment: If I could make a pun : bit by bit.... But it is actually four bits at a time 0b00 00= 0x0, 0b1111 = 0x0F. But the result will not fit into any of the standard C++ types. So you probably still have to put it into a string of sorts.

Comment: If you're bent on using `sha256`, you could directly convert the `bitset<256>` to a string of `256` characters, all of which are zeros/ones, via [bitset::to_string](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/bitset/to_string). This will at least allow you to take `bitresult` and compute `sha256` in one line.

Comment: @PepijnKramer You just have to nybble at it

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Convert binary bitset to hexadecimal (C++)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19461478/convert-binary-bitset-to-hexadecimal-c)

Answer (score 0):

Not much different to what you did, but more generic, and it would work with  sizes of `unsigned long long`:

```cpp
template <std::size_t N>
std::string bitset_to_hex(const std::bitset<N> &bs) {
    std::ostringstream os;
    static const std::bitset<N> MASK {(unsigned long long)-1};// all FFs
    static const std::size_t BITS_PER_NUMBER = sizeof(unsigned long long)*8; //bits per unsigned long long
    for (int i = BITS_PER_NUMBER; i<=N; i+=BITS_PER_NUMBER) {
        os << std::hex << std::setfill('0') << std::setw(BITS_PER_NUMBER/4) << ( (bs>>(N-i)) & MASK).to_ullong();
    }   
    return os.str();
}
```

You then just call it:

```cpp
return sha256(bitset_to_hex);
```