# Substring out of range when converting string to lowercase

Tags: c++, tolower

I'm attempting to take an input from the command line and then convert it to lower case. To do this, I've written:

```
istream& operator>>(istream& is, Card& c)
{
    static map<string,Card::Rank> mr = createmr();
    static map<string,Card::Suit> ms = createms();

    string srank, c1, ssuit;

    if (is >> srank >> c1 >> ssuit)
    {
        if (c1 == "of")
        {
            string nsrank;
            string nssuit;
            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < srank.length(); i++) {
                char temp = srank[i];
                nsrank[i] = tolower(srank[i]);
            }
```

It fails on the second iteration of that for loop (more precisely, it fails on `nsrank[i] = tolower(srank[i]);`). The error that is displayed is "string substring out of range" but I don't understand how this could be the case as there are definitely still characters left in the string.

To give an example:
If I enter "Ace of Spades" then it will iterate through the first time (when i=0) and transfer the 'a' fine. However, it then goes back through with i equaling 1 (which should refer to the 'c') but instead it tells me the substring is out of range (even though the assignment to the `char temp` works fine). During debugging, "nsrank" claims a size of 15 so I don't see how that could be out of range either....

Comment: I'd say the problem is in the `nsrank[i]` the `string nsrank` [creates an empty string](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/string/).

Comment: In addition of @jsantander comment, you really have the problem in all interations (in despite the runtime only detected it at the second one): `nsrank[i]` is an out of range access for all `i`, since `nsrank` is not initialized, so its size is 0.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that nsrank is an empty string, so accessing with [operator[]](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/operator%5B%5D/)....

> If pos is not greater than the string length, the function never
>   throws exceptions (no-throw guarantee). Otherwise, it causes undefined
>   behavior.

This one worked for me: http://ideone.com/3LcYqv

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    string srank="Ace of Spades";
    string nsrank;

    nsrank.resize(srank.length());

            for(unsigned int i = 0; i < srank.length(); i++) {
                char temp = srank[i];
                nsrank[i] = tolower(srank[i]);
            }
    cout << nsrank << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The key is the [resize](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/resize/) to make nsrank the same size as srank.

### Edit: Added compact solution

From many places, among them from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735215/308705)

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

string srank="Ace of Spades";
string nsrank=srank;
std::transform(nsrank.begin(), nsrank.end(),nsrank.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Comment: +1, but you need `<ctype.h` for `::toupper`. Also, there's usually a safety hack to protect against negative signed `char`.

Answer (score 0):

resize nsrank to match size of srank before entering the loop