# Switch statement and user input in C++

Tags: c++, string, compiler-errors, switch-statement, label

I am having some trouble using a `switch` statement with user input. Can anyone please explain what is going on? I am sorry if this is a noob question as I'm very used to Python and just started learning C++.

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
#include <cstdlib>    
    
int main()
{
    string name;
    cout << "Enter a name: ";
    cin >> name;
    switch (name){
        case name == "Seth":
            std::cout << "That's my name!";
            return 0;
            break;
        case name == "seth":
            std::cout << "Wow, you couldnt even put correct capitalization on my name...\n";
            std::cout << "LEARN YOUR PRONOUNS AND GO BACK TO SCHOOL!";
            return 0;
            break;
        case name == "SETH":
            std::cout << "Ok ok you spelled my name right but make sure you turn off caps lock please";
            return 0;
            break;
        default:
            std::cout << "Come on get my name RIGHT!!!\n";
            std::cout << "But you entered " << name;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That's not the correct syntax for `case` statements, though it doesn't matter because you cannot `switch` on `std::string` anyway

Comment: For strings, you'll need to use either `if-else-if` ladder or a lookup table.

Comment: In C++, `case` specifies values which are matched, not a condition.  So conceptually, in your sample, `case "Seth":`.  However, as UnholySheep mentioned, you can't use a String in a case, only integer types (char,, short, int, unsigned, etc).

Comment: You also don't need a return 0; after every case. That can just be outside all of them.

Comment: C++. Python. Different languages these are. Different languages with different ways. These new ways, [learn you must](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why the switch statement cannot be applied on strings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650162/why-the-switch-statement-cannot-be-applied-on-strings)

Answer (score 3):

According to the C++ 17 Standard (9.4.2 The switch statement)

> 2 The condition shall be of integral type, enumeration type, or class
> type. **If of class type, the condition is contextually implicitly
> converted (Clause 7) to an integral or enumeration type.** If the
> (possibly converted) type is subject to integral promotions (7.6), the
> condition is converted to the promoted type. Any statement within the
> switch statement can be labeled with one or more case labels as
> follows: case constant-expression : where the constant-expression
> shall be a converted constant expression (8.20) of the adjusted type
> of the switch condition. No two of the case constants in the same
> switch shall have the same value after conversion.

The class `std::string` does not have an implicit conversion operator that converts an object of the type `std::string` to an integral or enumeration type.

So the expression in this switch statement

```
switch (name){
```

is invalid.

Also case labels like this

```
case name == "seth":
```

are syntactically incorrect.

You could resolve your problem with the switch statement for example the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <array>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main()
{
    std::array<const char *, 3> names =
    {
        "Seth", "seth", "SETH"
    };

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    size_t n = std::find( std::begin( names ), std::end( names ), name ) - 
                          std::begin( names );

    switch (n)
    {
    case 0:
        std::cout << "That's my name!";
        break;

    case 1:
        std::cout << "Wow, you couldnt even put correct capitalization on my name...\n";
        std::cout << "LEARN YOUR PRONOUNS AND GO BACK TO SCHOOL!";
        break;

    case 2:
        std::cout << "Ok ok you spelled my name right but make sure you turn off caps lock please";
        break;

    default:
        std::cout << "Come on get my name RIGHT!!!\n";
        std::cout << "But you entered " << name;
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    std::string name;
    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
    std::cin >> name;
    
    if(name == "Seth")
    {
        std::cout << "That's my name!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(name == "seth")
    {
        std::cout << "Wow, you couldn't even put correct capitalization on my name..." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "LEARN YOUR PRONOUNS AND GO BACK TO SCHOOL!" << std::endl;
    }
    else if(name == "SETH")
    {
        std::cout << "Ok ok you spelled my name right but make sure you turn off caps lock please" << std::endl;
    }
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Come on get my name RIGHT!!!" << std::endl;
        std::cout << "But you entered " << name << std::endl;
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Tactical note: If you [convert `name` to all-lower or all-upper case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23418390/how-to-convert-a-c-string-to-uppercase), you can greatly reduce the number of `if`s required.

Comment: @user4581301 but user wants to show different output for specific spellings. I assume user is trying to learn about `switch` `case` statements.

Comment: Agreed. That's why it's a comment and not an answer.

Answer (score 0):

As other people have told that you can not do string comparison in `switch` and provided a solution. But I would like to use `enum class` which I found more readable and `int` comparison much more faster than `string` comparison.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <string>
#include <unordered_map>

int main() {
    enum class Spellings { Seth, seth, SETH };

    const std::unordered_map<std::string, Spellings> spellings_map{
        {"Seth", Spellings::Seth},
        {"seth", Spellings::seth},
        {"Seth", Spellings::SETH},
    };

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Enter a name: ";
    std::cin >> name;

    auto result = spellings_map.find(name);
    if (result == spellings_map.end()) {
        std::cout << "Come on get my name RIGHT!!!\n";
        std::cout << "But you entered " << name;
        return -1;
    }
    switch (result->second) {
        case Spellings::Seth:
            std::cout << "That's my name!";
            break;

        case Spellings::seth:
            std::cout << "Wow, you couldnt even put correct capitalization on "
                         "my name...\n";
            std::cout << "LEARN YOUR PRONOUNS AND GO BACK TO SCHOOL!";
            break;

        case Spellings::SETH:
            std::cout << "Ok ok you spelled my name right but make sure you "
                         "turn off caps lock please";
            break;
    }
}
```