# If statement always executing even when the condition is false?

Tags: c++, if-statement

when it gets to this if statement, no matter what 'option' is inputted  its always setting if(option == "y" || "Y") condition to true?

```
bool UserInterface::readInConfimDeletion() const
{
    string option = "";
    cout << "Are you sure you want to delete these transactions? Y/N "; 
    cin >> option;

    if (option == "y" || "Y")
    {
        return true;
    }
    else if (option == "n" || "N")
    {
        return false;
    }
    else{
        readInConfimDeletion();
        }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I compare strings in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)

Comment: @EJP this is c++ not java

Comment: The bottom line is to not treat C++ `if` conditions as if you're speaking English.  *If option equals 'Y' or 'y'* may be understandable when speaking, but C++ doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 4):

You can't compare multiple conditions like this:

```
if (option == "y" || "Y")
```

The "Y" condition will evaluate to `true` always if evaluated.

you need to do this:

```
if (option == "y" || option== "Y")
```

It would be simpler IMO to uppercase the string and perform a single comparision, there are a number of options to do this: [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case)

So a possible solution would be:

```
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
string upperStr = boost::to_upper_copy(option);
```

then you can do:

```
if (upperStr == "Y")
```

Comment: Sadly, `std::toupper` only works for `char`, and option is a `std::string`.  Still the best thing to do, but [with a library or simple support function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case), or operating on `option[0]`, or changing `option` to `char` (all slightly different implications/compromises).

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out, for some reason I thought this would work, shouldn't `std::toupper(option.c_str())` work though?

Comment: Nope... `std::toupper` won't accept the `const char*` `.c_str()` returns... I wish it was that easy!  You can use `std::toupper(*option.c_str())`, but that's equivalent to `std::toupper(option[0])` anyway.  The link in my comment above lists some options for handling full strings....

Answer (score 2):

Change it like this:

```
if (option == "y" || option ==  "Y")
```

and similarly

```
else if (option == "n" || option == "N")
```

You cannot compare multiple strings like the way you are doing.

Answer (score 2):

You need to say `option == "y" || option == "Y"` etc..

FYI / `if (option == "y" || "Y")` is actually asking if `option == "y"` or... `"Y"` itself is `true`, and `"Y"` is a string literal that undergoes a Standard Conversion to `const char*` then - being used inside an `if` undergoes a further conversion to the `bool` `true` (because the pointer is not `nullptr`, it's deemed `true`).