# error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Tags: c++, char

I'm trying to convert all the words into capital letters. Here's the header:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

using namespace std;

int Mayusculas(char texto)
{
    int liCount;
    for(liCount=0;liCount<strlen(texto);liCount++)
    {
        texto[liCount]=toupper(texto[liCount]);
    }
}
```

Here is the definition in main

```
char Cadena[100];
```

and here is where I am using it

```
case 1:
    Mayusculas(Cadena);
    cout<<Cadena<<endl;
```

The error message is

> error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'

Comment: What exactly is the problem? you mention that "I'm block(ed) with this error" - what is the error?

Comment: "this error"? well, next time post it.

Comment: It is said in the title @Shapiroyaacov **error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'**

Comment: Sorry, I thought that the title **error: invalid conversion from 'char' to 'const char*'** was explicit enough @KarolyHorvath.

Comment: @ANDY it is explicit enough, actually. Although, one might argue it's also pretty clearly telling you what went wrong.

Comment: I'm confused: you accepted vishal's answer, but it has errors, and it's still not working for you...? Please see my answer, which includes links to working demos.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

change your code to: as int may not fit into receiver type char

```
int Mayusculas(char *texto)
{
    int liCount;
    for(liCount=0;liCount<strlen(texto);liCount++)
    {
        texto[liCount]= (char) toupper(texto[liCount]);
    }
}
```

Comment: The same error, is still apearing. I doesn't need to change anything of the main?

Comment: @vishal, your suggestions for changes to main() are all incorrect. `char *Cadena[100];` is an array of `char *`s, not `char`s. You do not need to have the [100] in `Mayusculas(Cadena);` (if the compiler even allows it). And `cout<<*Cadena<<endl;` will only output the first character of the string.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR:

- [Demo using C-style strings](https://ideone.com/qfg2Kd)
- [Demo using `std::string`](https://ideone.com/HNMMG3)

## Details

Since we're primarily English-speaking, I'll note that it appears that [Mayusculas](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/mayuscula) indicates capital letters, and [cadena](http://www.spanishdict.com/translate/cadena) is a series or chain - in this case a C-style string.

### As Presented - C-style Strings

1. `int Mayusculas(char texto)` should be `int Mayusculas(char *texto)`

It needs to be a `char *` since you are working with a C-style string, and not a single character. Otherwise you have nothing to iterate through.

2. `toupper()` returns an `int`, so you should cast, i.e. change

`texto[liCount]=toupper(texto[liCount]);`

to

`texto[liCount] = (char)toupper(texto[liCount]);`

3. The function signature says you're returning an `int`, but you don't actually return anything. So either change it to return void, or return something. (`liCount`, maybe?)

### Alternative: std::string

But you tagged this question as C++, so why not use [`std::string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string) instead of C-style strings? They're safer, and easier to work with.

Quoting Pierre from [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735215/1995714):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>

std::string str = "Hello World";
std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(),str.begin(), ::toupper);
```

Or if you still want it in your own function,

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

string Mayusculas(std::string str)
{
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
    return str;
}

int main()
{
    string Cadena = "Hola al Mundo";
    cout << Mayusculas(Cadena) << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

That way returns the result as a string. But if you want to modify it in place like your original, you can do this instead. See it work [at Ideone](https://stackoverflow.com/a/735215/1995714).

```
void Mayusculas(std::string & str) // reference parameter
{
    transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);
}

int main()
{
    string Cadena = "Hola al Mundo";
    Mayusculas(Cadena);
    cout << Cadena << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you have to pass the address of the string, so instead of `char`, you have to use `char*`, like this in your function:

```
void Mayusculas(char *text)
{
    for(int post = 0; pos < std::strlen(text); pos++)
    {
        text[post] = (char) toupper(text[pos]);
    }
}
```

**Note:** The `char *text` indicated the address of the first character in your string.

The definition in the `main` function is good, so you can use it like this:

```
int main() {
  // ...
  char Cadena[100];
  Mayusculas(Cadena);

  std::cout << Cadena << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

I have also written an example that you can execute and test [here](http://cpp.sh/6lx4j).