# Twice the same for loop: one compiles, the other does not

Tags: c++, string, c++11, dictionary

I have this piece of code to make a couple of strings lower case (see [this SO post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case#735215)).

```
void some_free_standing_function(std::string solver, std::map<std::string, option_t> opts) {

    for (auto & c : solver) c = tolower(c);
    for (auto p : opts)
        for (auto & c : p.first)
            c = tolower(c);
}
```

The first range-based `for` seems to compile, the last one does not: Clang gives me `error: cannot assign to variable 'c' with const-qualified type 'const char &'`.

**Why does the first one pass but not the second one, given that they are exactly the same?**

Comment: OT: if it would compile it would still be useless becaus you modify a copy of the original map.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that the `value_type` of [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is `std::pair<const Key, T>`, that means for `p.first` you'll get a `const` `std::string`, and then the type of `c` will be `const char&`, which can't be modified.

The 1st one code snippet doesn't have such issue; `solver` is a non-const `std::string`.