# If Statements with more than one argument needing to be true?

Tags: c++, string, if-statement

I'm taking my first coding class and I've hit a road block. I'm writing a program that will need to pick out the second and third characters in a set of either 4 or 5 characters that gives a corresponding output based off the values it finds.

Here's an example of some of what I have thus far.

```
include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;
int main()
{ //start of main function
system("cls");
string parts = " ";
char input = ' ';


cout << "******** Part Number Program ********" << endl << endl;
cout << "Enter the part number (x to end): ";
getline(cin, parts);

while (parts != "x" || parts != "X")
{   //start while



    if (parts.substr(1, 1) == "M" && parts.substr(2, 1) == "P")//start if
    {
        cout << "Mail - Prioity" << endl << endl;
    }//end if
    else if (parts.substr(1, 1) == "F" && parts.substr(2, 1) == "S")//start if
    {
        cout << "FedEx - Standard" << endl << endl;
    }//end if
```

This works except with the exception of lowercase letters. For example, if I were to enter 7MP7 I'd get the output Mail-Prioity. However, if I enter 7mp7 I'd get my error message. Any suggestion on how I can fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Comment: You could use [`std::toupper`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper) to convert your characters to upper case.

Comment: Rather than comparing 1 length substrings, it seem more intuitive to compare characters. For example, `parts[1] == 'M'` instead of `parts.substr(1, 1) == "M"`.

Comment: `parts != "x" || parts != "X"` this will always be `true`. I think you wanted `parts != "x" && parts != "X"`

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux I guess I'm a little lost on where I would add the toupper? I've tried it and it doesnt work, but I'm positive thats because I'm using it wrong

Comment: Did you notice that `parts.substr(1, 1) == "M" && parts.substr(2, 1) == "P"` is the same as `parts.substr(1, 2) == "MP"` ?

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string data = "This Will Be All UpperCase When After The Next Line Code";
    transform(data.begin(), data.end(), data.begin(), ::toupper);
    cout << data << endl;
}
```

Comment: Search the internet for "c++ transform string tolower" for an example of how to use library functions to convert to all lower case.

Answer (score 0):

You can compare the characters using a case-insensitive comparison function such as `strcasecmp`. See documentation [here](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_72/rtref/strcasecmp.htm).

```
if (srtcasecmp(parts.substr(1, 1).c_str(), "M") == 0 && srtcasecmp(parts.substr(2, 1).c_str(), "P") == 0) {//your code}
```

Or even cleaner:

```
if (srtcasecmp(parts.substr(1, 1).c_str(), "M") & srtcasecmp(parts.substr(2, 1).c_str(), "P") == 0) {//your code}
```

Comment: Why do you consider using binary `and` a cleaner solution? I think it is not only not cleaner but unnecessary less efficient. Plus you are trying to pass `std::string` where `const char *`  is expected

Comment: @Slava fixed using c_str()

Comment: I still do not get why you consider using bitwise and "cleaner"

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in one the comments,

```
while (parts != "x" || parts != "X")
```

is not right. The conditional will always evaluate to `true`. It needs to be:

```
while (parts != "x" && parts != "X")
```

You can simplify the logic in the loop using:

```
char secondLetter = std::tolower(parts[1]);
char thirdLetter = std::tolower(parts[2]);

if ( secondLetter == 'm' && thirdLetter == 'p' )
{
  // ...
}
else if ( secondLetter == 'f' && thirdLetter == 's' )
{
  // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your input string to uppercase or lowercase using one of the methods you like from [Convert a String In C++ To Upper Case](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case) and then just check:

```
// convert parts to uppercase here
while (parts != "X")
{   
    if (parts.substr(1, 2) == "MP" )
    {
        cout << "Mail - Prioity" << endl << endl;
    }
    ...
```

Note: though you should comment your code, but to comment obvious things, for example this is start of `if` (like you cannot get it from code itself) is considered bad practice.