# Is there any equivalent to 'strupr' for Xcode (C++) in Mac?

Tags: c++, xcode, macos

I'm trying to use a code I found online for a bigger algorithm and Xcode doesn't support this function. I tried using the library curses.h (because conio.h is not defined in Xcode) but I couln't find an equivalent command.

Comment: It's pretty trivial to implement this yourself.

Comment: I actually study Maths so I'm not that good implementing, that's why I'm asking, if you could help I would really appreciate it.

Comment: [Like these solutions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case).

Answer (score 3):

In Xcode  there is no built-in function to uppercase a string, but you can easily write one like so:

```
std::string strToUpper(std::string str)
{
    std::transform(str.begin(), str.end(), str.begin(), ::toupper);

    return str;
}
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!