# Passing C-Style string char * to function argument

Tags: c++, function, pointers, c-strings

I want to change the characters in a string passed by user, converted into a C-style string and passed as an argument to a function with a char * argument:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>

void functoupper(char *myString)
{
    int i=0;
    char z;
    do {
        z= myString[i];
        myString[i]=toupper(z);
        ++i;
    } while(myString[i]!=0);
}

int main() {

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name in small caps: ";
    std::getline (std::cin,name);
    const char *myString = name.c_str();
    std::cout << "Hello, " << functoupper(myString) << "!\n";

    return 0;   
}
```

I get error error: invalid conversion from 'const char*' to 'char*' [-fpermissive] when calling function functoupper(myString) in main().

Comment: Why not simply: `void functoupper(std::string& myString)`. The condition here should be `while(i < myString.size());` then.

Comment: It's pretty clear: If it's const you cant alter it. You need to make a copy. As this is C++, just use `std::string` and forget about C strings.

Comment: `std::transform(begin(name), end(name), begin(name), std::toupper)`

Comment: `std::cout << "Hello, " << functoupper(myString) << "!\n";` is nonsense regardless. The function returns `void`.

Comment: Since you are using C++, I suggest using the C++ header file `#include <cstdlib>`.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude: little nitpicking - `transform` works most of the time, [but not always](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/735204/convert-a-string-in-c-to-upper-case).

Answer (score 3):

The [`std::string::c_str()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/c_str) method returns a pointer to `const char` data, but your function expects a pointer to non-const `char` data.  That is why you are getting an error.

You could use [`const_cast`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/const_cast) to cast away the `const` (but that is not really advisable):

```cpp
char *myString = const_cast<char*>(name.c_str());
functoupper(myString);
std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
```

You could use the non-const [`std::string::operator[]`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/operator_at) to access the string's underlying character data (just be careful because prior to C++11, characters were not *required* to be stored contiguously in memory, but *most* `std::string` implementations did):

```cpp
functoupper(&name[0]);
std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
```

In C++17 and later, you can use the non-const [`std::string::data()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/data) method instead:

```cpp
functoupper(name.data());
std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";
```

That being said, heed this warning when using [`toupper()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/toupper):

> Like all other functions from `<cctype>`, the behavior of `std::toupper` is undefined if the argument's value is neither representable as `unsigned char` nor equal to `EOF`. To use these functions safely with plain `char`s (or `signed char`s), the argument should first be converted to `unsigned char` ... Similarly, they should not be directly used with standard algorithms when the iterator's value type is `char` or `signed char`. Instead, convert the value to `unsigned char` first

With that said, try something more like this:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cctype>

void functoupper(char *myString)
{
    for (int i = 0; myString[i] != '\0'; ++i) {
        unsigned char z = static_cast<unsigned char>(myString[i]);
        myString[i] = static_cast<char>(std::toupper(z));
    }
}

int main() {

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name in small caps: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    functoupper(&name[0]); // or name.data()
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

    return 0;   
}
```

That being said, you should just pass the entire `std::string` as-is into your function instead, and then you can manipulate it as needed, for instance with the [`std::transform()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/transform) algorithm:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

void functoupper(std::string &myString)
{
    std::transform(myString.begin(), myString.end(), myString.begin(),
      [](unsigned char ch){ return std::toupper(ch); }
    );
}

int main() {

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name in small caps: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    functoupper(name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << name << "!\n";

    return 0;   
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cctype>

std::string functoupper(std::string myString)
{
    std::transform(myString.begin(), myString.end(), myString.begin(),
      [](unsigned char ch){ return std::toupper(ch); }
    );
    return myString;
}

int main() {

    std::string name;

    std::cout << "Please, enter your full name in small caps: ";
    std::getline(std::cin, name);
    std::cout << "Hello, " << functoupper(name) << "!\n";

    return 0;   
}
```

Answer (score 2):

As @Someprogrammerdude and @RemyLebeau comment, why not <s>simply</s>:

```
std::transform(std::begin(name), std::end(name), std::begin(name), 
    [](const unsigned char c)
    {
        return std::toupper(c);
    });
```

But if you must do it via a `char*`, then you'll need to copy the data over first, something like:

```
char myString* = new char[name.size() + 1];
strcpy(myString, name.c_str());
```

EDIT: Thanks to the helpful comments by @RemyLebeau

Better still avoid all the memory management issues with the above by simply coping your `std::string` into a `std::vector`:

```
std::vector<char> myVec(std::begin(name), std::end(name));
myVec.push_back(`\0`);
```

and then call your `char*` function with:

```
functoupper(myVec.data());
```

Comment: Consider using `std::vector` instead of `new[]`.  Also, when using `toupper()`, you need to cast `char` values to `unsigned char` or you can end up with bad results when `char` is signed, which means you should not use `toupper` as the actual `transform` predicate, use a lambda or functor that casts chars as needed.

Comment: If you are going to use `string::size()` to allocate a `char[]` array, consider using `string::copy()` instead of `strcpy()` to copy the string's chars into the array