# Identical functions have different performance, why?

Tags: c, performance, x86-64, performance-testing, intel

I made a program to test performance of different functions, that do the same in different ways. However, some of them generate the almost exact same machine code except for different addresses and when i measure the execution time one of them is faster than the other. This happens consistently in almost every run and i have no idea why. Strange is also that when i remove some other test functions, the difference dispersal. I wrote the code for [another](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64104679/does-moving-out-a-unchanged-computation-out-of-a-loop-improve-a-programs-perfor/64107902#64107902) answer on StackOverflow and want to understand why.

I run on Debian 10 Buster, AMD64 and use GCC. I compile it with `-O3`.
Below is my code. The function `lowerA()` is almost every time faster than `lower9()`, despite the same code  If i remove the unused functions `lower1()`-`lower8()` the difference goes away.

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

#include <time.h>


//#define DEBUG


#ifdef DEBUG
  #define N 10
#else
  #define N 1000UL*100
#endif

#define M 20

#define STR_(x) #x
#define STR(x) STR_(x)



void lower1(char *s)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] -= ('A' - 'a');
    }
  }
}

void lower2(char *s)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t len = strlen(s);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] -= ('A' - 'a');
    }
  }
}

void lower3(char *s)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  int d='A'-'a';

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] -= d;
    }
  }
}

void lower4(char *s)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t len = strlen(s);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] += 0x20;
    }
  }
}

void lower5(char *s)
{
  size_t i;

  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] += ('a' - 'A');
    }
  }
}

void lower6(char *s)
{
  size_t i;
  for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] |= 0x20;
    }
  }
}

void lower7(char *s)
{
  size_t i;
  size_t len = strlen(s);

  for (i = 0; i < len; i++)
  {
    if (s[i] >= 'A' && s[i] <= 'Z')
    {
      s[i] |= 0x20;
    }
  }
}

void lower8(char *s)
{
  size_t len = strlen(s);
  while(len--)
    {
      if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z')
      {
        *s |= 0x20;
      }
      s++;
    }
}

void lower9(char *s)
{
  while(1)
  {
    if (!*s)
    {
      break;
    }
    if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z')
    {
      *s |= 0x20;
    }
    s++;
  }
}

void lowerA(char *s)
{
  while(*s)
  {
    if (*s >= 'A' && *s <= 'Z')
    {
      *s |= 0x20;
    }
    s++;
  }
}

uint64_t die(const char *msg)
  {
    fprintf(stderr,"die: %s : %s\n",msg,strerror(errno));
    exit(1);
  }

uint64_t getTime(void)
  {
    uint64_t time;
    struct timespec  t_v;
    if(clock_gettime(CLOCK_BOOTTIME,&t_v)<0)
      {
        die("cant get time");
      }
    time=t_v.tv_sec*1000000000ULL;
    time+=t_v.tv_nsec;
    return time;
  }
  

void test(void (*fp)(char *),char (*s)[M],const char *name)
  {
    static char (*copy)[M];
    copy=malloc(N*M);
    if(!copy)
      {
        die("can't alloc memory");
      }
    memcpy(copy,s,N*M);
    uint64_t start=getTime();
    for(size_t u=0;u<N;u++)
      {
        fp(copy[u]);
      }
    uint64_t end=getTime();
    printf("time %13"PRIu64" %s\n",end-start,name);
    #ifdef DEBUG
      for(size_t u=0;u<N;u++)
        {
          printf("%3zu %"STR(M)"s %"STR(M)"s\n",u,s[u],copy[u]);
        }
    #endif
    free(copy);
  }
  
void runTest(void)
{
  //create a random string
  srand(getTime());
  static char string[N][M];
  for(size_t u=0;u<N;u++)
  {
    size_t l=rand()%M;
    for(size_t i=0;i<l;i++)
    {
      string[u][i]=rand()%('z'-'/')+'/';
    }
    string[u][l]='\0';
  }
  #define TEST(s) test(s,string,STR(s))
  TEST(lower9);
  TEST(lowerA);
}

int main(void)
{
  for(unsigned i=0;i<8;i++)
  {
    runTest();
  }
  return 1;
}
```

This is the disassembly of the function `lower9()` and `lowerA()`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function lower9:
   0x00000000000017b0 <+0>: movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x00000000000017b3 <+3>: test   %al,%al
   0x00000000000017b5 <+5>: je     0x17eb <lower9+59>
   0x00000000000017b7 <+7>: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x00000000000017c0 <+16>:    lea    -0x41(%rax),%edx
   0x00000000000017c3 <+19>:    cmp    $0x19,%dl
   0x00000000000017c6 <+22>:    ja     0x17e0 <lower9+48>
   0x00000000000017c8 <+24>:    or     $0x20,%eax
   0x00000000000017cb <+27>:    add    $0x1,%rdi
   0x00000000000017cf <+31>:    mov    %al,-0x1(%rdi)
   0x00000000000017d2 <+34>:    movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x00000000000017d5 <+37>:    test   %al,%al
   0x00000000000017d7 <+39>:    jne    0x17c0 <lower9+16>
   0x00000000000017d9 <+41>:    retq   
   0x00000000000017da <+42>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x00000000000017e0 <+48>:    add    $0x1,%rdi
   0x00000000000017e4 <+52>:    movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x00000000000017e7 <+55>:    test   %al,%al
   0x00000000000017e9 <+57>:    jne    0x17c0 <lower9+16>
   0x00000000000017eb <+59>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
Dump of assembler code for function lowerA:
   0x00000000000017f0 <+0>: movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x00000000000017f3 <+3>: test   %al,%al
   0x00000000000017f5 <+5>: je     0x182b <lowerA+59>
   0x00000000000017f7 <+7>: nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001800 <+16>:    lea    -0x41(%rax),%edx
   0x0000000000001803 <+19>:    cmp    $0x19,%dl
   0x0000000000001806 <+22>:    ja     0x1820 <lowerA+48>
   0x0000000000001808 <+24>:    or     $0x20,%eax
   0x000000000000180b <+27>:    add    $0x1,%rdi
   0x000000000000180f <+31>:    mov    %al,-0x1(%rdi)
   0x0000000000001812 <+34>:    movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x0000000000001815 <+37>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001817 <+39>:    jne    0x1800 <lowerA+16>
   0x0000000000001819 <+41>:    retq   
   0x000000000000181a <+42>:    nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001820 <+48>:    add    $0x1,%rdi
   0x0000000000001824 <+52>:    movzbl (%rdi),%eax
   0x0000000000001827 <+55>:    test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001829 <+57>:    jne    0x1800 <lowerA+16>
   0x000000000000182b <+59>:    retq   
End of assembler dump.
```

One example result, sorted:

```
time       4145299 lowerA
time       4153573 lowerA
time       4155081 lowerA
time       4158537 lowerA
time       4173954 lowerA
time       4190982 lowerA
time       4196201 lowerA
time       4202252 lower9
time       4209932 lower9
time       4214722 lowerA
time       4215861 lower9
time       4216471 lower9
time       4243532 lower9
time       4315601 lower9
time       4323003 lower9
time       4331462 lower9
```

Why is `lowerA()` a tiny bit faster?

**Edit**
with clang i do not get the same behavior.

**Edit2**
Swapping the calls for `lower9()` and `lowerA()` makes `lower9()` faster.
(Editor's note: as described in [Idiomatic way of performance evaluation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60291987/idiomatic-way-of-performance-evaluation), that can mean insufficient warm-up, or in this case more likely that it comes down to some fiddly difference in code alignment after inlining.  Especially given that clang showed no difference.)

**Edit3**
I use a Intel [Xeon CPU W3570](https://ark.intel.com/content/www/us/en/ark/products/39722/intel-xeon-processor-w3570-8m-cache-3-20-ghz-6-40-gt-s-intel-qpi.html)  @ 3.20GHz, [Bloomfield microarchitecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bloomfield_(microprocessor)), aka Nehalem server.

**Edit4**
`gcc --version` gives `gcc (Debian 8.3.0-6) 8.3.0`

Peter Cordes said the code could be inlined, i think he is correct, this is the dissasemply of `runTest()`:

```
Dump of assembler code for function runTest:
   0x00000000000019d0 <+0>: push   %r15
   0x00000000000019d2 <+2>: mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x00000000000019d7 <+7>: push   %r14
   0x00000000000019d9 <+9>: push   %r13
   0x00000000000019db <+11>:    push   %r12
   0x00000000000019dd <+13>:    push   %rbp
   0x00000000000019de <+14>:    push   %rbx
   0x00000000000019df <+15>:    sub    $0x58,%rsp
   0x00000000000019e3 <+19>:    mov    %rsp,%rsi
   0x00000000000019e6 <+22>:    callq  0x1050 <clock_gettime@plt>
   0x00000000000019eb <+27>:    test   %eax,%eax
   0x00000000000019ed <+29>:    js     0x1cd1 <runTest+769>
   0x00000000000019f3 <+35>:    imul   $0x3b9aca00,(%rsp),%rdi
   0x00000000000019fb <+43>:    add    0x8(%rsp),%rdi
   0x0000000000001a00 <+48>:    xor    %r14d,%r14d
   0x0000000000001a03 <+51>:    xor    %r13d,%r13d
   0x0000000000001a06 <+54>:    callq  0x1080 <srand@plt>
   0x0000000000001a0b <+59>:    nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001a10 <+64>:    callq  0x10e0 <rand@plt>
   0x0000000000001a15 <+69>:    mov    %eax,%ebx
   0x0000000000001a17 <+71>:    mov    $0x66666667,%eax
   0x0000000000001a1c <+76>:    imul   %ebx
   0x0000000000001a1e <+78>:    mov    %ebx,%eax
   0x0000000000001a20 <+80>:    sar    $0x1f,%eax
   0x0000000000001a23 <+83>:    sar    $0x3,%edx
   0x0000000000001a26 <+86>:    sub    %eax,%edx
   0x0000000000001a28 <+88>:    lea    (%rdx,%rdx,4),%eax
   0x0000000000001a2b <+91>:    shl    $0x2,%eax
   0x0000000000001a2e <+94>:    sub    %eax,%ebx
   0x0000000000001a30 <+96>:    movslq %ebx,%rbx
   0x0000000000001a33 <+99>:    test   %rbx,%rbx
   0x0000000000001a36 <+102>:   je     0x1a78 <runTest+168>
   0x0000000000001a38 <+104>:   lea    0x2681(%rip),%rax        # 0x40c0 <string.3410>
   0x0000000000001a3f <+111>:   mov    $0x1b4e81b5,%ebp
   0x0000000000001a44 <+116>:   lea    (%rax,%r14,1),%r15
   0x0000000000001a48 <+120>:   lea    (%rbx,%r15,1),%r12
   0x0000000000001a4c <+124>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000001a50 <+128>:   callq  0x10e0 <rand@plt>
   0x0000000000001a55 <+133>:   add    $0x1,%r15
   0x0000000000001a59 <+137>:   mov    %eax,%ecx
   0x0000000000001a5b <+139>:   imul   %ebp
   0x0000000000001a5d <+141>:   mov    %ecx,%eax
   0x0000000000001a5f <+143>:   sar    $0x1f,%eax
   0x0000000000001a62 <+146>:   sar    $0x3,%edx
   0x0000000000001a65 <+149>:   sub    %eax,%edx
   0x0000000000001a67 <+151>:   imul   $0x4b,%edx,%edx
   0x0000000000001a6a <+154>:   sub    %edx,%ecx
   0x0000000000001a6c <+156>:   add    $0x2f,%ecx
   0x0000000000001a6f <+159>:   mov    %cl,-0x1(%r15)
   0x0000000000001a73 <+163>:   cmp    %r12,%r15
   0x0000000000001a76 <+166>:   jne    0x1a50 <runTest+128>
   0x0000000000001a78 <+168>:   lea    0x0(%r13,%r13,4),%rax
   0x0000000000001a7d <+173>:   lea    0x263c(%rip),%rdi        # 0x40c0 <string.3410>
   0x0000000000001a84 <+180>:   add    $0x1,%r13
   0x0000000000001a88 <+184>:   add    $0x14,%r14
   0x0000000000001a8c <+188>:   lea    (%rdi,%rax,4),%rax
   0x0000000000001a90 <+192>:   movb   $0x0,(%rax,%rbx,1)
   0x0000000000001a94 <+196>:   cmp    $0x186a0,%r13
   0x0000000000001a9b <+203>:   jne    0x1a10 <runTest+64>
   0x0000000000001aa1 <+209>:   mov    $0x1e8480,%edi
   0x0000000000001aa6 <+214>:   callq  0x10b0 <malloc@plt>
   0x0000000000001aab <+219>:   mov    %rax,%r12
   0x0000000000001aae <+222>:   mov    %rax,0x1eaa8b(%rip)        # 0x1ec540 <copy.3400>
   0x0000000000001ab5 <+229>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000001ab8 <+232>:   je     0x1cdd <runTest+781>
   0x0000000000001abe <+238>:   lea    0x25fb(%rip),%rsi        # 0x40c0 <string.3410>
   0x0000000000001ac5 <+245>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000001ac8 <+248>:   mov    $0x1e8480,%edx
   0x0000000000001acd <+253>:   callq  0x10a0 <memcpy@plt>
   0x0000000000001ad2 <+258>:   lea    0x10(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001ad7 <+263>:   mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x0000000000001adc <+268>:   callq  0x1050 <clock_gettime@plt>
   0x0000000000001ae1 <+273>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001ae3 <+275>:   js     0x1cd1 <runTest+769>
   0x0000000000001ae9 <+281>:   mov    0x18(%rsp),%rbp
   0x0000000000001aee <+286>:   mov    %r12,%rsi
   0x0000000000001af1 <+289>:   imul   $0x3b9aca00,0x10(%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000001afa <+298>:   lea    0x1e8480(%r12),%rdi
   0x0000000000001b02 <+306>:   nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001b08 <+312>:   movzbl (%rsi),%eax
   0x0000000000001b0b <+315>:   mov    %rsi,%rdx
   0x0000000000001b0e <+318>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001b10 <+320>:   je     0x1b35 <runTest+357>
   0x0000000000001b12 <+322>:   nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001b18 <+328>:   lea    -0x41(%rax),%ecx
   0x0000000000001b1b <+331>:   cmp    $0x19,%cl
   0x0000000000001b1e <+334>:   ja     0x1c88 <runTest+696>
   0x0000000000001b24 <+340>:   or     $0x20,%eax
   0x0000000000001b27 <+343>:   add    $0x1,%rdx
   0x0000000000001b2b <+347>:   mov    %al,-0x1(%rdx)
   0x0000000000001b2e <+350>:   movzbl (%rdx),%eax
   0x0000000000001b31 <+353>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001b33 <+355>:   jne    0x1b18 <runTest+328>
   0x0000000000001b35 <+357>:   add    $0x14,%rsi
   0x0000000000001b39 <+361>:   cmp    %rdi,%rsi
   0x0000000000001b3c <+364>:   jne    0x1b08 <runTest+312>
   0x0000000000001b3e <+366>:   lea    0x20(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001b43 <+371>:   mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x0000000000001b48 <+376>:   callq  0x1050 <clock_gettime@plt>
   0x0000000000001b4d <+381>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001b4f <+383>:   js     0x1cd1 <runTest+769>
   0x0000000000001b55 <+389>:   lea    0x4e6(%rip),%rdx        # 0x2042
   0x0000000000001b5c <+396>:   lea    0x4d0(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2033
   0x0000000000001b63 <+403>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001b65 <+405>:   imul   $0x3b9aca00,0x20(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001b6e <+414>:   sub    %rbp,%rsi
   0x0000000000001b71 <+417>:   add    0x28(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001b76 <+422>:   sub    %rbx,%rsi
   0x0000000000001b79 <+425>:   callq  0x1070 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000001b7e <+430>:   mov    0x1ea9bb(%rip),%rdi        # 0x1ec540 <copy.3400>
   0x0000000000001b85 <+437>:   callq  0x1030 <free@plt>
   0x0000000000001b8a <+442>:   mov    $0x1e8480,%edi
   0x0000000000001b8f <+447>:   callq  0x10b0 <malloc@plt>
   0x0000000000001b94 <+452>:   mov    %rax,%r12
   0x0000000000001b97 <+455>:   mov    %rax,0x1ea9a2(%rip)        # 0x1ec540 <copy.3400>
   0x0000000000001b9e <+462>:   test   %rax,%rax
   0x0000000000001ba1 <+465>:   je     0x1cdd <runTest+781>
   0x0000000000001ba7 <+471>:   lea    0x2512(%rip),%rsi        # 0x40c0 <string.3410>
   0x0000000000001bae <+478>:   mov    %rax,%rdi
   0x0000000000001bb1 <+481>:   mov    $0x1e8480,%edx
   0x0000000000001bb6 <+486>:   callq  0x10a0 <memcpy@plt>
   0x0000000000001bbb <+491>:   lea    0x30(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001bc0 <+496>:   mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x0000000000001bc5 <+501>:   callq  0x1050 <clock_gettime@plt>
   0x0000000000001bca <+506>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001bcc <+508>:   js     0x1cd1 <runTest+769>
   0x0000000000001bd2 <+514>:   mov    0x38(%rsp),%rbp
   0x0000000000001bd7 <+519>:   mov    %r12,%rsi
   0x0000000000001bda <+522>:   imul   $0x3b9aca00,0x30(%rsp),%rbx
   0x0000000000001be3 <+531>:   lea    0x1e8480(%r12),%rdi
   0x0000000000001beb <+539>:   nopl   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001bf0 <+544>:   movzbl (%rsi),%eax
   0x0000000000001bf3 <+547>:   mov    %rsi,%rdx
   0x0000000000001bf6 <+550>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001bf8 <+552>:   je     0x1c1d <runTest+589>
   0x0000000000001bfa <+554>:   nopw   0x0(%rax,%rax,1)
   0x0000000000001c00 <+560>:   lea    -0x41(%rax),%ecx
   0x0000000000001c03 <+563>:   cmp    $0x19,%cl
   0x0000000000001c06 <+566>:   ja     0x1cb0 <runTest+736>
   0x0000000000001c0c <+572>:   or     $0x20,%eax
   0x0000000000001c0f <+575>:   add    $0x1,%rdx
   0x0000000000001c13 <+579>:   mov    %al,-0x1(%rdx)
   0x0000000000001c16 <+582>:   movzbl (%rdx),%eax
   0x0000000000001c19 <+585>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001c1b <+587>:   jne    0x1c00 <runTest+560>
   0x0000000000001c1d <+589>:   add    $0x14,%rsi
   0x0000000000001c21 <+593>:   cmp    %rsi,%rdi
   0x0000000000001c24 <+596>:   jne    0x1bf0 <runTest+544>
   0x0000000000001c26 <+598>:   lea    0x40(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001c2b <+603>:   mov    $0x7,%edi
   0x0000000000001c30 <+608>:   callq  0x1050 <clock_gettime@plt>
   0x0000000000001c35 <+613>:   test   %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001c37 <+615>:   js     0x1cd1 <runTest+769>
   0x0000000000001c3d <+621>:   lea    0x405(%rip),%rdx        # 0x2049
   0x0000000000001c44 <+628>:   lea    0x3e8(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2033
   0x0000000000001c4b <+635>:   xor    %eax,%eax
   0x0000000000001c4d <+637>:   imul   $0x3b9aca00,0x40(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001c56 <+646>:   sub    %rbp,%rsi
   0x0000000000001c59 <+649>:   add    0x48(%rsp),%rsi
   0x0000000000001c5e <+654>:   sub    %rbx,%rsi
   0x0000000000001c61 <+657>:   callq  0x1070 <printf@plt>
   0x0000000000001c66 <+662>:   mov    0x1ea8d3(%rip),%rdi        # 0x1ec540 <copy.3400>
   0x0000000000001c6d <+669>:   callq  0x1030 <free@plt>
   0x0000000000001c72 <+674>:   add    $0x58,%rsp
   0x0000000000001c76 <+678>:   pop    %rbx
   0x0000000000001c77 <+679>:   pop    %rbp
   0x0000000000001c78 <+680>:   pop    %r12
   0x0000000000001c7a <+682>:   pop    %r13
   0x0000000000001c7c <+684>:   pop    %r14
   0x0000000000001c7e <+686>:   pop    %r15
   0x0000000000001c80 <+688>:   retq   
   0x0000000000001c81 <+689>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000001c88 <+696>:   add    $0x1,%rdx
   0x0000000000001c8c <+700>:   movzbl (%rdx),%eax
   0x0000000000001c8f <+703>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001c91 <+705>:   jne    0x1b18 <runTest+328>
   0x0000000000001c97 <+711>:   add    $0x14,%rsi
   0x0000000000001c9b <+715>:   cmp    %rdi,%rsi
   0x0000000000001c9e <+718>:   jne    0x1b08 <runTest+312>
   0x0000000000001ca4 <+724>:   jmpq   0x1b3e <runTest+366>
   0x0000000000001ca9 <+729>:   nopl   0x0(%rax)
   0x0000000000001cb0 <+736>:   add    $0x1,%rdx
   0x0000000000001cb4 <+740>:   movzbl (%rdx),%eax
   0x0000000000001cb7 <+743>:   test   %al,%al
   0x0000000000001cb9 <+745>:   jne    0x1c00 <runTest+560>
   0x0000000000001cbf <+751>:   add    $0x14,%rsi
   0x0000000000001cc3 <+755>:   cmp    %rsi,%rdi
   0x0000000000001cc6 <+758>:   jne    0x1bf0 <runTest+544>
   0x0000000000001ccc <+764>:   jmpq   0x1c26 <runTest+598>
   0x0000000000001cd1 <+769>:   lea    0x33a(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2012
   0x0000000000001cd8 <+776>:   callq  0x1850 <die>
   0x0000000000001cdd <+781>:   lea    0x33c(%rip),%rdi        # 0x2020
   0x0000000000001ce4 <+788>:   callq  0x1850 <die>
End of assembler dump.
```

**Edit5** The inlined parts are also identical, as far i understand it.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/222201/discussion-on-question-by-12431234123412341234123-identical-functions-have-diffe).

Comment: `for (i = 0; i < strlen(s); i++)` calling `strlen` in a loop is already a bad idea, and why do you sometimes store the length in a variable but sometimes call it in the loop?

Comment: @phuclv: That's leftover noise from a Q&A about that: [Does moving out a unchanged computation out of a loop improve a program's performance?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64104679).  Note the first paragraph where the OP links to their answer there.  Unfortunately they didn't remove those unused function versions for a [mcve] of this `lower9` vs. `lowerA` experiment.

Comment: @PeterCordes When i remove this functions, i get a different behavior, that is why i left this functions.

Comment: @phuclv I know that this is a bad idea, my question was not which is the most efficient code. My question is only about the difference between `lower9()` and `lowerA()` that only exist when i include the other unused functions.

Answer (score 1):

You gave us one key observation

> If i remove the unused functions lower1()-lower8() the difference goes
> away.

That shows that it has nothing to do with the different `lowerX()` implementations, but with the location in memory, probably via affecting the cache hit/miss ratio. And it's not only the `lowerX()` function's location in memory, but more the combination with its calling function's location that influences the caches and thus the results.

That means that the effect depends on the overall memory layout of your final executable.

- The memory layout in turn depends on the compiler toolchain and its settings, the order in which your functions are found in the source files, and probably a lot of additional influences.
- Even for a given memory layout, the performance effect will vary a lot for different CPU / cache versions. So a different machine you might just give you the opposite results.

Anyway, as long as the performance difference is so tiny (2 or 3 percent), I can hardly imagine an application where that matters, especially in a function like uppercasing that rarely dominates real-world applications.

Comment: *probably via affecting the cache hit/miss ratio* - This code has very small I-cache footprint compared to how many times the loops run.  Much more likely branch predictor aliasing or not.  Note that this code actually branches on each character, instead of doing something efficient with SIMD or branchless scalar, so we expect lots of mispredicts.  A small difference in mispredict chance (e.g. from the conditional branch aliasing an outer loop branch) could account for it.  But yes, overall agreed that it's not very significant.