# How to resolve a name conflict between a system header macro and a boost template function?

Tags: c++, boost, xlc

What is the best way to resolve a conflicting macro name with a boost template function?
After including boost/chrono.hpp I got the compiler error:

> CCN5816 (W) Too many arguments are specified for the macro "round". The extra arguments are ignored.
>   "/usr/include/math.h", line 2133.16: CCN5425 (I) "round" is defined on line 2133 of "/usr/include/math.h".

`round` conflicts with the template function `boost::chrono::round`.

*/usr/include/math.h*

```
#define round(x)         __round(x)
```

*/boost/chrono/round.hpp*

```
namespace boost
{
  namespace chrono
  {

    /**
     * rounds to nearest, to even on tie
     */
    template <class To, class Rep, class Period>
    To round(const duration<Rep, Period>& d)
    {
```

- It seems that I can either `#undef` the macro if I patch round.hpp
- Maybe I can use parantheses? In the answer to [macro and member function conflict](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1394132/237483) the function name is within parentheses but this is in the usage of the function, not in its definition. Would it work in the definition too?

*BoostChronoTest.cpp*

```
#include <gtest/gtest.h>
#include <boost/chrono.hpp>

TEST(BoostChronoTest, simpleTests) {
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds ns(12000);

    // conversion with precision loss requires a cast
    boost::chrono::microseconds ms = boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(ns);

    // no precision loss
    boost::chrono::nanoseconds  ns2 = ms;

    ms++;
    ms += boost::chrono::duration_cast<boost::chrono::microseconds>(ns);
    ns *= 2;
    EXPECT_TRUE(ms > ns);
    EXPECT_EQ(ms, boost::chrono::microseconds(25));
    EXPECT_EQ(ns, boost::chrono::nanoseconds(24000));
    EXPECT_EQ(ns2, boost::chrono::microseconds(12));
    EXPECT_EQ(ns2, boost::chrono::nanoseconds(12000));
}
```

Comment: Ha, this seems like a classic example why not to use macros, but you can't tell the standard library that, I figure...

Comment: @Downvoter Indeed, and quite bad form on the libraries writer's part to destroy such a common name as `round`.

Answer (score -1):

Simply, *always* including `<gtest/gtest.h>` *after* `<boost/chrono.hpp>`: that way the `#define round ...` won't affect the boost code.

Comment: I didn't include math.h or cmath, they must come with gtest.h (I can't compile now to verify the other include order)

Comment: Thanks for your input, I will try your suggestions and leave a comment if it worked