# Which is better #define PI or const double PI?

Tags: c++, c++11, math, macros, pi

Which is better:

```
#define PI 3.14
```

or

```
const double PI = 3.14;
```

This was an interview question, and I don't seem to find an unambiguous answer.

I suppose I should prefer not to use macros, but I'd like to have a sturdy answer to this.

**EDIT:** 
So the [question marked duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274008/why-would-someone-use-define-to-define-constants) says, that define "don't respect scopes", but I don't really want scopes here, I want something like a super global, PI must be PI everywhere, should be accessed from anywhere. #define seems more reasonable here to me.

Also I don't see where could using PI go wrong in compile time so please provide an example.

Comment: id argue that it depends on your target platform. more specifically, the way the compiler creates the assembly and the underlying cpu instruction set. Just as a for instance, if you #define a constant double, and the compiler emits it as an immediate value, an instruction might become 2-4 bytes larger than if it simply emitted a reference to a memory location. 2-4 bytes 10000 times adds up to not a whole hell of a lot. BUT if you only have 4kb of code space on your target platform, you might want to do something else.

Answer (score 0):

You would want PI to be constant and be in the scope for as much the app runs so static const PI would be good