# In C++, is it better to use #define or const to avoid magic numbers?

Tags: c++, constants, c-preprocessor

What are the advantages and disadvantages of using #define over const (and vice versa)?

When I read about bad programming practices specifically magic numbers, I found myself using #define more frequently. Some questions popped into my mind such as:

Is it bad to use #define a lot?
Does it take memory space?
Would it be faster to use const instead?

I read a bit about this but I'm still not sure, from what I've understood:
 #define defines a macro (not sure what macro means) and it deals with pre-processing. It replaces all instances of the defined keyword into something else before the code is being processed. const on the other hand is variable whose value cannot be changed midway during runtime.

The only reason I can think of using const is if the value relies on other variables. For example:

```
#define PI 3.14159f
#define RADIUS 3.0f
#define AREAOFCIRCLE PI*RADIUS*RADIUS
```

would be inefficient since every instance of AREAOFCIRCLE would be replaced by PI*RADIUS*RADIUS so the program would compute for it everytime you use AREAOFCIRCLE. On the other hand:

```
const float areaofcircle = PI*RADIUS*RADIUS;
```

would be more effecient since the program would  only compute for it once.

So back to the original question, how does #define compare to const?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6274008/why-would-someone-use-define-to-define-constants?rq=1

Comment: I've read that but I'm not satisfied with any of the answers

Comment: Is it bad to use `#define` a lot? Try not to use it at all!

Comment: how about constexpr?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is #define bad and what is the proper substitute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715831/why-is-define-bad-and-what-is-the-proper-substitute)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Don't worry about efficiency in this case since all of them will be computed in compile-time.

You should stop using Macros (at least to define constants) whenever you can. Macros are wild things against namespaces and scopes. On the other hand `const` objects have *type* and this can reduce unintended mistakes.

It's always useful to read Stroustrup's piece of advises: [***"So, what's wrong with using macros?"***](http://www.stroustrup.com/bs_faq2.html#macro)

Comment: what does "all of them computes in compile-time." mean?

Comment: It doesn't matter you're using Macro or const, in both case the result of `PI*RADIUS*RADIUS` will be computed in compile-time and final value  will be replaced to assign.

Comment: so does that mean #define AREAOFCIRCLE PI*RADIUS*RADIUS would only be computed by the program once and not everytime you call AREAOFCIRCLE?

Comment: Yes, in run-time you have the calculated value everywhere you used `AREAOFCIRCLE`.

Comment: Macros used to define manifest constants have types. With `#define SIZE 1`, `SIZE` has type `int`.

Comment: @PeteBecker: Yes, they have the default types that compiler choose them not the types may the programer wants. However the programmer can insert the actual type by `#define SIZE ((size_t)1)` but it's ugly!

Answer (score 4):

"const" in C++ is invaluable. Consts enforce type checking in expressions while the "#define"d constants are just expanded.

Moreover as the constants are typed the compiler can interfere better optimizations while with defines it has to guess (1.0 is a float or a double? Using suffixes as 1.0d or 1.0f might help, but I have seldom seen real numbers written so consciously...).

So use consts for defining constants

```
const float PI = 3.14159f;
const float RADIUS = 3.0f;
const float AREAOFCIRCLE = PI*RADIUS*RADIUS;
```

You will get at least the same compile time optimizations + some additional type check.

Comment: `1.0` is double. There is nothing to guess.

Answer (score -1):

"const" is more efficient due to it takes up memory once and be referenced every where. In contrast, "#define" will take up space and addition operation anywhere it be used.

Comment: why would #define take up space? I thought it only does literal text substitution?

Comment: when #define be used, it may produce addition operation depend on compiler

Comment: I mean where the substitution is used, it takes up memory.