# Difference between preprocessor macros and std::source_location

Tags: c++, c++20, c++-faq

There are some predefined preprocessor macros (specified in C and C++ standard) like `__line__` and `__file__` which are replaced by line number and file name during preprocessing respectively. In C++20, a new class `std::source_location` is introduced which does more or less the same thing.

#### So, my questions are...

- What are the differences between them?
- What are their advantages and disadvantages?
- Which one I should use for which reason?

Comment: As stated on [cpp reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location), "It is intended that source_location has a small size and can be copied efficiently.

Comment: One difference is that with `std::source_location` objects you no longer need "ugly" macros for many things, you can use simple functions (as shown in e.g. [this example](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location#Example)).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preprocessor macros live outside the type system. Preprocessor macro substitution happens outside the rest of the language. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14041453/why-are-preprocessor-macros-evil-and-what-are-the-alternatives) and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4715831/why-is-define-bad-and-what-is-the-proper-substitute) for a comprehensive discussion of the disadvantages of using the preprocessor.

`std::source_location` on the other hand behaves like any other C++ struct. It has plain value fields that are typed and behave like any other values in the language.

Besides that, functionality-wise the two mechanisms are equivalent. There is nothing that the one can achieve that cannot be done by the other (apart from the [column field](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/source_location/column) in `source_location`, which has no equivalent in the preprocessor). It's just that the new approach achieves its goals more nicely.

Comment: You cannot paste `source_location` line with another token. With `__LINE__` it is a way to create unique identifiers.

Comment: @n.'pronouns'm.: There are way to create unique identifier without MACRO.(template taking type with lambda)

Comment: @Jarod42 That would not be an identifier ;) It works 99% of the time, but you cannot create an enum this way for example. There are probably other ways to achieve any particular result though.