# Find an array element position in compile time

Tags: c, metaprogramming

-- Edited --

Hi all. I've got an array of elements that will not change in all the execution of the program, and where items can have sons inside the own array. I've got to prepare the array before process it. However, because I know that the array will not change, I would like to declare it as `const`, and prepare all of it in compile time, so I could throw away the integers `int son_id[NUM_OF_SONS]`, `prepare_items()` function and the array declaration will be, in my opinion, clearer.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

#define NUM_OF_SONS 5

struct item{
    int id;
    char *str;
    int son_id[NUM_OF_SONS];
    const struct item *son[NUM_OF_SONS];
};

const struct item *find_item(int id);

static struct item items[] = {
    {4, "FIRST ELEMENT"},
    {5, "SECOND ELM"},
    {10, "THIRD ELM"}, 
    {15, "FATHER", {5,10}},
    {0, 0 }
};

const struct item *find_item(int id){
    int i;
    for(i=0; items[i].str != NULL; ++i){
            if(items[i].id == id) return &items[i];
    }

    return NULL;
}

void fill_sons(struct item *item){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_SONS;++i){
            if(item->son_id[i]!=0)
                    item->son[i] = find_item(item->son_id[i]);
    }
}

void prepare_items(){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<sizeof(items)/sizeof(items[0]);++i){
            fill_sons(&items[i]);
    }
}

void print_sons(const struct item *item);

void print_item(const struct item *item){
    printf("The item %d has the text %s.\n",item->id,item->str);
    print_sons(item);
}

void print_sons(const struct item *item){
    int i;
    for(i=0;i<NUM_OF_SONS;++i){
            if(NULL!=item->son[i])
                    print_item(item->son[i]);
    }
}

int main(){
    prepare_items();

    print_item(&items[0]);
    print_item(&items[3]);
}
```

I've though in something like this:

```
static struct item items[] = {
    {4, "FIRST ELEMENT"},
    {5, "SND ELM"},
    {10, "THIRD ELM"},
    {15, "FATHER", {&items[1],&items[2]}},
    {0, 0 }
};
```

However, there could be about 200 elements in the array, and I need to be able to insert or delete elements in the middle of it (in compile time). So `&items[1],&items[2]` should be `ITEM_ID(5),ITEM_ID(10)`, some kind of preprocessor instruction. How could achieve that?

Thanks in advance, and sorry for the long post.

Comment: Where the items are in the array is known at compile time because it's the same order they are in the initializer list in the source code. For instance I can tell that array element `0` has the `item` with id number 4. Please clarify, perhaps with an example of code you'd *like* to be able to write, but can't.

Comment: I think what the OP is asking for is a way that is independent of the order of the initializer elements. For example, to allow him to insert an item numbered 5 in index 1, moving item 5 down to index 2, etc. I don't know of a compile-time way so the best I can suggest is an indexing array, initialized at the start of run-time, which indexes the items array. For example, index 10 if the indexer would point at index 2 of the example items array. (Non-existent indexers would contain NULL.)

Comment: Please, consider explaining your problem further. Right now, by looking to the part above, over the *-- long version --* line, I would recommend doing `int searchedID = 4; int i = 0; while ( items[i].id != searchedID ) if ( ++i > sizeof items ) { /* doesn't exist */ break; }` and `i` would in the end be the index of the element that holds the ID `searchedID = 4`, but I have the feeling that what is being asked is not this simple. Maybe it's the language...

Comment: I'm Sorry, I'll try to explain myself better.

Comment: @DoxyLover, I can't do this because the id could be, for example, 50000. I can't hold a 50000-length array where 99% of the array is NULL element.

Comment: @turbulencetoo, that's good for a list with 2 or 3 elements length. But what if the list is 200 or 300 elements length? Or if I want to add some element in the middle of the list? what I'm looking for is a way that the compiler tell me that item with element id 4 is in the position 0 (i.e., metaprogramming)

Comment: @ThoAppelsin Exactly, that's the answer I want, but in compile time, i.e., using preprocessor macros. The same way I can use `sizeof(items)/sizeof(items[0])` to know the length of the list, I would like some for/while bucle using preprocessor macros. At the moment, I'm using some function like your's to initialize the structure, but I'm using 5 integers in each elements to store something that I'm almost sure I can obtain in compilation time.

Comment: Very sorry for the long post and thanks to all for the answers.

Comment: @user3473433 I don't think that's do-able.

Comment: There are many typos in your question; there are missing `S`'s or too many `S` at `MAX_NUMS_OF_CHILDS`, you miss a comma `,` after the `... 20}}`, you miss a semicolon `;` after the `const struct item items[]` declaration, you probably were meaning to write `20` instead of `120` for the 5th element, which kind of makes it hard to understand your given example.

Comment: @user3473433 I added an answer in the same minute the question was edited. Did you see it?

Comment: @user3473433 Yoohoo! Your problem is solved!

Comment: Sorry @luser droog, but I still cannot test your answer. It looks pretty good so far! I give you an answer asap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nearest equivalent to templates in C (that I know of) is X-Macros. I think you can achieve this result, but it will require introducing another identifier for each struct (**actually it doesn't -- scroll down to the "Edit"!**) which we can sync with the array by declaring these identifiers in an enum.

To start with, we change the initializer elements to be in the form of macro calls. For the style I prefer, the name of this macro is not important, so I'll call it `_`. All calls will need the same number of elements, so add an empty list where necessary. And the whole thing is wrapped in one big macro. This big macro will receive another macro as an argument which it calls for each element.

```
#define DATA(_) \
    _(4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(6, "SECOND_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(10, "FATHER ELEMENT", {15, 20}) \
    _(15, "SON ELEMENT 1", {}) \
    _(20, "SON ELEMENT 2", {}) \
    _(0, NULL, {})
```

Now we can declare the array data by defining a usage macro that emit the arguments in the correct form for the array declaration.

```
#define CREATE_ARRAY(a, b, c) \
    {a, b, c},

struct item items[] = {
DATA(CREATE_ARRAY)
}
```

So far we've just achieved the same result. But now it's in a more flexible form. The next step is adding the new IDs.

```
#define DATA(_) \
    _(FIRST, 4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(SECOND, 6, "SECOND_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(FATHER, 10, "FATHER ELEMENT", {15, 20}) \
    _(SON1, 15, "SON ELEMENT 1", {}) \
    _(SON2, 20, "SON ELEMENT 2", {}) \
    _(END, 0, NULL, {})
```

And adjust the `CREATE_ARRAY` macro to account for the new argument.

```
#define CREATE_ARRAY(a, b, c, d) \
    {b, c, d},

struct item items[] = {
DATA(CREATE_ARRAY)
};
```

Now the fun part. We make another macro to generate the IDs as enum values.

```
#define CREATE_IDS(a, b, c, d) \
    a,

enum identifiers {
DATA(CREATE_IDS)
};
```

Now the data can use these identifiers to index the array.

```
#define DATA(_) \
    _(FIRST, 4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(SECOND, 6, "SECOND_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(FATHER, 10, "FATHER ELEMENT", {SON1, SON2}) \
    _(SON1, 15, "SON ELEMENT 1", {}) \
    _(SON2, 20, "SON ELEMENT 2", {}) \
    _(END, 0, NULL, {})
```

And, of course, remove the `child_id` member from the struct, since our new identifiers are the desired array indices, directly.

---

Edit. Wait a moment. You have identifiers already. And they're already unique. So we don't need to introduce new ones. We can simply mangle them! `__VA_ARGS__` is also needed to handle the possible embedded commas in the child list.

```
#define CREATE_ARRAY(a, b, ...) \
    {a, b, __VA_ARGS__ },

#define ID_(x) ID ## x
#define CREATE_IDS(a, b, ...) \
    ID_(a),


#define DATA(_) \
    _(4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(6, "SECOND_ELEMENT", {}) \
    _(10, "FATHER ELEMENT", {ID15, ID20}) \
    _(15, "SON ELEMENT 1", {}) \
    _(20, "SON ELEMENT 2", {}) \
    _(0, NULL, {}) 

enum identifiers {
DATA(CREATE_IDS)
};

struct item items[] = { 
DATA(CREATE_ARRAY)
};
```

`cpp -P` output (linebreaks added):

```
enum identifiers {
ID4, ID6, ID10, ID15, ID20, ID0,
};
struct item items[] = {
{4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", {} }, 
{6, "SECOND_ELEMENT", {} }, 
{10, "FATHER ELEMENT", {ID15, ID20} }, 
{15, "SON ELEMENT 1", {} }, 
{20, "SON ELEMENT 2", {} }, 
{0, NULL, {} },
};
```

---

For more about X-macros, see the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros) (one of which I wrote :P).

Comment: Whew! I've never heard about this! but it fits perfectly with the problem! Thanks! And I'm sorry, but I still can't vote your answer as useful, because I don't have reputation enough (in fact, this was my first question haha). But it will the first thing I'll do when I have! thanks a lot!

Comment: You're quite welcome. It was an interesting problem. Even though you can't vote (yet), you can click the check-mark to accept the answer. That's worth more than a vote. :)

Answer (score 0):

About the best I can offer--because C is absolutely not designed to keep track of this sort of metadata--is the `__LINE__` constant.

`__LINE__` inserts the current line number into the program, which you can use as a field in the `struct item`. Obviously, you need to also commit to not having any blank spaces in your definition of `items` and also know where `items` starts in the file.  The latter, you can do with something like:

```
int first_line = __LINE__ + 2;
const struct item items[] = {
    {4, "FIRST_ELEMENT", __LINE__},
```

And then remember to subtract `first_line` from your `line_id` (or whatever you want to call it) field.

It's not a *good* solution, but I think it's about the best that C is going to do without writing code to load the contents of one array into another and keep track of the metadata during the move.

Comment: How does this solve the problem really? How is he going to make use of this to, say, find out what the index of the element that has the `.id == 4`? What is he going to do, write `items[0].line_id - first_line`? Programme already would be knowing that it would result in `0`, since programme already put a `0` inside the square brackets.

Comment: What if I do something like this: I could define all the id with a macro, let's say, <br> `#define FOUR_ELEMENT 4<br> ... <br> DEFINE_ID(FOUR_ELEMENT)`. This `DEFINE_ID` macro will put in the code the 4, but, also, it will define FOUR_ELEMENT_POS to 1,2...N. The problem is that I have to keep this `preprocessor variable`, and find a way to auto-increment it. How do you see it? (PD: Can't I put line break here?)

Comment: That's why I suggested `__LINE__`. It's the line number of the file, so it _does_ auto-increment, and `__LINE__ - first_line` is the array index, assuming you don't have a blank line in your initialization. Oh, and no line-breaks in comments, probably because complex items should be edits or answers.

Comment: @ThoAppelsin, I assume the idea is for each record to know its index (`items[i].line_id - first_line`, where we don't already know `i`), since the program already knows the record at each index by indexing. So, the fourth record stores its `.line_id`, which is its index (which is metadata C doesn't store) plus `first_line`.

Answer (score 0):

First things first, you have to know that once you declare `items` as an array to constant item structures, which you do when you write `const struct item items[];`, you then won't be able to change the contents of those structures after initialization.

So, for example, you won't be able to assign anything to any of the elements of the `child` array inside any one of the structures inside the `items` array. Woah, that was big, let's give a code example:

```
items[2].child[0] = &( items[3] );
// or just ... items + 3;
// you won't be able to do this because items[2] is defined as a constant
```

I couldn't really understand what your objective is, but here's one thing that *possibly maybe* help you out. You can do the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MaximumChildCount 5 // personal preference, easier to read, change as you wish

typedef struct item{
    int id;
    char *str;
    // I left the childs_id out, since you've implied that you'd like that out
    struct item *child[MaximumChildCount];
};

int main( ){

    const struct item sons[] = {
        { 15, "SON ELEMENT 1" },
        { 20, "SON ELEMENT 2" }
    };
    // creating sons before the parent, biologically nonsense?
    // well, if you want to keep the record of child elements inside parent
    // and make them all constants, then you need to have children before

    const struct item items[] = {
        { 4, "FIRST_ELEMENT" },
        { 6, "SECOND_ELEMENT" },
        { 10, "FATHER ELEMENT", { sons, sons + 1 } },
        // sons points to first son, sons + 1 points to the second one
        // assigned them at initialization, just like you had with { 15, 20 }
        { 0, NULL }
    };

    printf( "%s", items[2].child[1]->str );

    return 0;
}
```

This prints `"SON ELEMENT 2"`. You can very well make sons in the following way:

```
const struct item son1 = { 15, "SON ELEMENT 1" };
const struct item son2 = { 20, "SON ELEMENT 2" };
```

And then assign them during initialization like this:

```
... = {
    ...
    ...
    { ..., ..., { &son1, &son2 } },

    ...
};
```

I'm sorry if this was not the thing you were looking for. I really am having hard times on understanding the cause.

Comment: I'm very sorry for the typos, ThoAppelsin. I should have double-checked the code before of write it down here. The point of all this it's that I do not want changes in the array, and I know what positions of the array holds the son element. However, it could be about 200 or 300 elements in the array, and I cannot manage so large array. I'll try to rewrite the question.