# Can array elements have identifiers?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, identifier, c++03

I am currently defining some constants:

```
struct ModInfo {
    int numChoices;
    string menu;

    ModInfo (int count, string menuText) : numChoices(count), menu(menuText) {
    }
};

const ModInfo menus[4] = {ModInfo(3, "..."), ModInfo(7, "...", ...};
```

Each `ModInfo` contains the information for a module that will be used by `main()` in printing menus to the display and flow control to determine which module's menu to print and which function in it to subsequently execute.

Instead of accessing a module's info inside an array element via array index, can I assign an identifier (ie. the module's name) to that element instead? Is there a direct way to do this, or is `enum` the only hack to do this?

Edit: Please stop asking me to use C++11 in every question I ask. I would if I could.

Comment: I tagged as C++03. You should use this tag if you're restricted to pre-C++11 dialects.

Comment: Wrong terminology: identifier usually refer to tokens in the source code.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch It's not wrong terminology. I am asking if array elements can be mapped to an identifier during development, not a string value that will persist into the build.

Comment: @thegreatjedi: If you want to use an identifier, then I don't see why enums are a hack. Could you include in your question some pseudocode that describes what you'd like to do?

Comment: Is it sufficient to have the module identifier be an actual C++ identifier (e.g. a constant), or do you need something you can specify at runtime, e.g. a string?

Comment: @BillLynch There's not much more to it. Any use is just accessing the array. I just want to give a name to the elements I'm accessing instead of index numbers for readability. Wouldn't enums be considered kinda like a crude way of getting it done, or is it considered an appropriate design?

Comment: @FrerichRaabe I only want something more readable than index numbers during development.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than being a hack, an `enum` is the correct tool for your use case.

Answer (score 1):

You could set up your array using an [X macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros):

```
#define MODULES \
  X(MenuItemA, 24, "some menu text") \
  X(AnotherMenuItem, 99, "here's another menu item" )
```

Then, you define both the array of menus as well as an enum with descriptive constants from the same table by defining `X` appropriately:

```
#define X(id, count, text) ModInfo(count, #text),
const ModInfo menus[] = {
  MODULES,
  ModInfo(-1, "")
};
#undef X

#define X(id, count, text) id,
struct ModuleId {
   enum Value {
MODULES
   };
};
#undef X
```

You could then access your module information via e.g.

```
menus[ModuleId::AnotherMenuItem].text;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use C++11 (perhaps even as a tag). You might use some recent version of [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) or of [Clang/LLVM](http://clang.llvm.org/) (perhaps by compiling a compiler from its source code), both are [free software](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Free_software).

<sup>(versions of C++ before [C++11](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11) are obsolete; and the current standard is C++14; if you need an old version of C++ you should tag appropriately your question)</sup>

You should learn about C++ [containers](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) and [smart pointers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smart_pointer) and you might use `std::map<std::string,std::unique_ptr<ModInfo>>` to associate to some (name) string a pointer to your `ModInfo`

Read a good book about [Programming using C++](http://stroustrup.com/programming.html); BTW reading [SICP](https://mitpress.mit.edu/sicp/) and practicing some Scheme won't harm.

Comment: C++11 is not available to me in my environment. Secondly, I am not looking for a way to map a string to the element. I'm looking for a way to map identifiers (variable names) to the element.

Comment: Then upgrade your compiler to some more recent version.

Comment: Upgrading isn't an option. The version is determined by the organization and has to follow conventions set by partner institutions.

Comment: Then you should have tagged your question with the obsolete version of C++ that you need to use. I am sorry for you. IIRC, `std::map` existed in some old versions of C++

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I can't see why C++11 is needed at all (given that I can't see why unique_ptr is needed at all.)

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Really? I wouldn't have known whether the solution I seek is only available in C++11 or not. My question is not a C++11-specific issue, nor is it a C++03-specific issue, why does it necessarily need a C++xx tag instead of C++?

Comment: @thegreatjedi Because C++ is now C++14, which is includes the C++11 functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps then a structure with named fields would be more convenient if the size of the array is not too big.

```
struct MyNamedStruct
{
    int NamedVariable1;
    int NamedVariable2;
    ...
    int NamedVariableX;
};

MyNamedStruct a;
...
a.NamedVariable1 = 10;
```