# Using a macro as an argument in an x-macro definition

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, x-macros

Consider the following user-style [x-macro](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6635851/149138):

```
#define PRIMES_X(func) \
  func(2) \
  func(3) \
  func(5)
```

We can use this to call a passed-in macro `func` repeatedly with first three primes. For example:

```
#define MAKE_FUNC(num) void foo ## num();
PRIMES_X(MAKE_FUNC)
```

Would declare the void-returning functions `foo2()`, `foo3()` and `foo5()`.

So far, so good. Now let's say I want to use a macro in the definition of the x-macro itself, as an argument, as follows:

```
#define MAX_PRIME 5
#define PRIMES_X(func) \
  func(2) \
  func(3) \
  func(MAX_PRIME)
```

It doesn't work, because `MAKE_FUNC` will now try to declare `void fooMAX_PRIME()`, as (I suppose) the token concatenation happens without expanding `MAX_PRIME`.

Can I fix this so that it declares `foo5()` as before?

Comment: On a side note out of curiosity, are you going to use the x_macro with `#undef`s?

Comment: @Yunnosch - no, I don't currently undef things like `MAKE_FUNC`. One of the benefits of the user-form.

Comment: Exactly. May I ask where you picked up that undef-free version of x_macros? I ask because some time ago I claimed the invention here at StackOverflow, asking for references to any "previous art". So I am very interested in your source, even if it means that I have to stop claiming it.

Comment: Here's [the link](http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/the-x-macro/228700289). The article is not by Andrei but see the comment at the bottom: _Of course, you may already be using a macro or variable named X, and X is hardcoded in the macro body. Andrei Alexandrescu suggests the following improvement where the X macro is itself a parameter..._, but there isn't a reference trail beyond that. The comment thread is also interesting, people pointing out that x-macros get lost from time to time. I consider them at least semi-mainstream now that they have a wikipedia page ... @Yunnosch

Comment: Thanks, I will study it later.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can insert another level of macro-expansion (`PRIMES_X2` below).

```
#define MAKE_FUNC(num) void foo ## num();
#define MAX_PRIME 5
#define PRIMES_X(func) PRIMES_X2(func, MAX_PRIME)
#define PRIMES_X2(func, maxPrimePar) \
  func(2) \
  func(3) \
  func(maxPrimePar)

PRIMES_X(MAKE_FUNC)
```

Output with `gcc -E`:

```
void foo2(); void foo3(); void foo5();
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked perfectly for the [real use case in my project](https://github.com/travisdowns/uarch-bench/commit/f28703d1c53c5dcc476d2ec3bf2d39cd100b5edf#diff-65670f3dc051237b53613ab20060709bR30).

Answer (score 1):

The answer by Yunnosch is fine, but to spin the X macro insanity a bit further, you could also do this with a macro call inside the list, rather than a wrapper macro outside it. The advantage of this is that you can pass "variables" from the list to the called macro.

I suppose this could have some use - suppose for example that you wish to use the X macro to declare functions of different types?

Example:

```
#define MAX_PRIME 5

#define CREATE_FUNC(func, ret_type, param) func(ret_type, param)

#define PRIMES_X(func)                 \
  CREATE_FUNC(func, int,    2)         \
  CREATE_FUNC(func, void,   3)         \
  CREATE_FUNC(func, double, MAX_PRIME) \

#define MAKE_FUNC(ret_type, num) ret_type foo ## num(void);
  PRIMES_X(MAKE_FUNC)
#undef MAKE_FUNC
```

Debug code to check that the functions did indeed get the expected prototypes:

```
int main(void)
{
  (void)foo2();
  foo3();
  (void)foo5();
}

int foo2 (void){ return 0;}
void foo3 (void){}
double foo5 (void){ return 0.0;}
```

Comment: Thanks, this technique works too! I don't quite follow the benefit relative to the other approach though - with the other approach, you could just as easily pass the `ret_type` argument by modifying `PRIMES_X2` to call `func(int, 2) \ func(void, 3)...` right?

Comment: @BeeOnRope The benefit of this version is that the type is part of the X macro list and not the caller code. The whole purpose of X macros is to centralize all maintenance to one single list - this version makes it possible to do so by letting the X macro list determine the types used. Seems handy, although I would of course if possible avoid macros that create functions in the first place.

Comment: Yup, I get that, but can't you do the exact same thing with the form of the other answer? Specifically, add the types into the `PRIMES_X2` list. I don't see how this approach allows this while the other doesn't.