# Get list entry of type T at compile-time

Tags: c++, templates, compile-time

I've a container class that stores some objects of an abstract class. In some parts, the program needs to get these objects as there implementation classes. I wrote a generic get function, but it has to loop through all stored objects, which can cost a lot of time. As I know that the container will only have one object of each type I want to solve this issue during compile-time, but don't want to create my own member for each type by hand.

At the moment I don't have trouble with the "wasted" runtime, but I want to learn how to solve this.

My current implementaion:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <list>

class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class ImplA : public Abstract
{
public:
    void update() {std::cout << "implA" << std::endl;}

};

class ImplB : public Abstract
{
public:
    void update() {std::cout << "implB" << std::endl;}

};

class Container
{
public:
    Container(){
        content.push_back(new ImplA);
        content.push_back(new ImplB);
    }

    void update() {
        for (Abstract* obj : content)
            obj->update();
    }

    template<typename T> T* get() const {
        for (Abstract* obj : content) {
            if(dynamic_cast<T*>(obj) != nullptr)
                return dynamic_cast<T*>(obj);
        }
        return nullptr;
    }

private:
    std::list<Abstract*> content;
};

int main()
{
    Container* container = new Container();
    container->get<ImplA>()->update();
    container->get<ImplB>()->update();
    return 0;
}
```

My ideas on how to solve this:

- create an own member and get function for each type
- Instead of using a list use a map and use the typeinfo.name as key (but that's a runtime solution and would be a bad idea)
- Implement a list of types (e.g. enum types {implA, implB}) and use this as map-key. Here I would have to create a new entry for each type.
- Using something like a compile-time map, which could use a type as a key.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe you could do something with some [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Curiously_recurring_template_pattern) trickery, to avoid the `dynamic_cast`s and replace them with `static_cast`s, which would be resolved at compile time.

Comment: I remember we've been solving a similar situation using `enum` and kind of [X macros](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6635851/real-world-use-of-x-macros), rather complicated stuff with framework implementation, and new devs on the team had a significantly steep learning curve how to implement new types properly (declare the class, add the new enum value, add a macro call for implementing the `getType()` function, etc.). I'd really consider if it's worth it to overcome this small runtime overhead you're facing.

Comment: @OP, is it always the case that all of the registrations are in the same place (`Container`'s constuctor here)? If not, that'd make the solution significantly more complicated, as they would need to be aggregated at link-time instead of compile-time.

Comment: @Quentin yes, the Container's constructor will always create all objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your objects are always inserted together, then your problem has already been solved by `std::tuple`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <tuple>

template <class... Ts>
struct Container : std::tuple<Ts...> {
    using std::tuple<Ts...>::tuple;

    void update() {
        std::apply([](auto &... objects){ (objects.update(), ...); }, *this);
    }
};

namespace std {
    template <class... Ts>
    struct tuple_size<Container<Ts...>> : tuple_size<tuple<Ts...>> { };
}

template <class... Ts>
Container(Ts...) -> Container<Ts...>;
```

`Container` supports [`std::get`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/get) through implicit conversion to `std::tuple` and the specialization of `std::tuple_size`.

[See it Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/4b88344dfd86c4b6) (tweaked for its pre-C++17 GCC :/)

Comment: Nice. I didn't know that C++14 added an overload of `get` with type argument. Why is the specialization of `tuple_size` necessary?

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf because `std::get` specializes it for its argument at some point, and that does't consider the implicit conversion to a base class -- it has to match exactly.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two main ways to provide constant time access to the objects of distinct types:

- Use multiple inheritance, cast down to the object type.
- Use a hash table (like `std::unordered_set`) indexed by `std::type_index`.

---

Example of the multiple inheritance approach, which provides compile time access:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

class Abstract
{
public:
    virtual void update() = 0;
};

class Impl_a : public Abstract
{
public:
    void update() override { cout << "impl A" << endl; }

};

class Impl_b : public Abstract
{
public:
    void update() override { cout << "impl B" << endl; }

};

template< class Type >
struct Boxed_
{
    Type object;
};

class Container:
    public Boxed_<Impl_a>,
    public Boxed_<Impl_b>
{
    vector<Abstract*> m_items;

    Container( const Container& ) = delete;
    auto operator=( const Container& ) -> Container& = delete;

public:
    void update()       // Not an override of base class function
    {
        for( Abstract* obj : m_items ) { obj->update(); }
    }

    template< class Type >
    auto get()
        -> Type*
    { return &static_cast<Boxed_<Type>&>( *this ).object; }

    Container():
        m_items{{ get<Impl_a>(), get<Impl_b>() }}
    {}
};

auto main()
    -> int
{
    Container c;
#ifdef INDIVIDUAL_CALLS
    c.get<Impl_a>()->update();
    c.get<Impl_b>()->update();
#else
    c.update();
#endif
}
```

If you want the container as `const` holder of references to non-`const` objects, just add an extra level of indirection.

That's the fundamental theorem of software engineering, by David Wheeler:

> **”** All problems in computer science can be solved by another level of indirection

Comment: That doesn't resolve the whole problem at compile time as the OP was requesting for.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ: It does.