# Macro for creating an enum and array entry at once

Tags: c, enums, macros, c-preprocessor

I have an array of strings (`char*`). For example:

```
char* strings[] = 
{
   "abc",
   "def",
   "ghi"
};
```

To best refer to them by their index, I need to create a separate enum:

```
typedef enum
{
     abc = 0,
     def,
     ghi

} enum_strings_t;
```

Assuming I often need to add new entries, I need to do it in 2 places- the `strings` array and `enum_strings_t` enum- need to manually keep them in sync.

My question is: can this be somehow fixed by a macro, meaning, that only 1 new entry (instead of 2) would update both the enum and the array? I am looking for a native way of doing this in C, without using external Python scripts that would manually edit the header file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use something what is called [Xmacro](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/X_Macro).

```
#define XMACRO(X) \
   X(abc) \
   X(def) \
   X(ghi)

#define TO_ENUM(NAME) NAME,
#define TO_STR(NAME)  #NAME,

enum enum_str {
XMACRO(TO_ENUM)
};

char *string[] = {
XMACRO(TO_STR)
};
```

It expands to:

```
enum enum_str {
abc, def, ghi,
};

char *string[] = {
"abc", "def", "ghi",
};
```

Comment: See also SO Q&A such as [Real-world use of X-Macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6635851/15168) and many others.

Comment: You have made me go deep into the rabbit hole...