# How to append something to comma-separated list (implemented as macro) and convert it to strings using C preprocessor?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have an list of tokens defined as:

```
#define TOKENS ACC, STOP, RUN, BACK
```

This list might change.
I would like to create an array of function pointers based on that list by doing something similar to:

```
int (*callbacks[])(const char * arg) =
{
   some_macro_shenanigans(TOKENS)
};
```

And `some_macro_shenanigans(TOKENS)` should expand to `ACC_callback, STOP_callback, ...` and so on. Later I would like to create an array of strings based on `TOKENS` like this:

```
const char * const token_str[] = some_other_macro_shenanigans(TOKENS);
```

Which would expand to something equivalent to this:

```
const char * const token_str[] = [ "ACC", "STOP", "RUN", "BACK" /* and others if present */ ];
```

Is it doable?

Comment: I think you need to look up "x-macros".  See, for example, [Real-world use of X-macros?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6635851/15168).  There's even a tag for questions about them: [tag:x-macros].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, using x-macros (as comments point towards):

```
#define TOKENS(DO) \
    DO(ACC) \
    DO(STOP) \
    DO(RUN) \
    DO(BACK) 

#define GEN_CALLBACK(ID) ID##_callback,
#define GEN_NAME(ID) #ID,

int (*callbacks[])(const char * arg) = { TOKENS(GEN_CALLBACK) };
const char * const token_str[] = [ TOKENS(GEN_NAME) ];
```

[preprocesses to (godbolt link)](https://godbolt.org/z/9Txq1sTeK)

```
int (*callbacks[])(const char * arg) = { ACC_callback, STOP_callback, RUN_callback, BACK_callback, };
const char * const token_str[] = [ "ACC", "STOP", "RUN", "BACK", ];
```