# Problems understanding the min and max declarations syntax in std::chrono::duration_values

Tags: c++, syntax, c++-chrono

I'm having a look at the piece of code below, from `std::chrono`, and I don't understand the `_Rep(min)()` syntax.

I know `_Rep` is the return type, and `min` has to be the method name, but then:

- What's the difference between writing it like `_Rep(min)()` and `_Rep min()`?
- And, why isn't the same done for `zero`?

```cpp
template <class _Rep>
struct duration_values { // gets arithmetic properties of a type
    _NODISCARD static constexpr _Rep zero() noexcept {
        // get zero value
        return _Rep(0);
    }

    _NODISCARD static constexpr _Rep(min)() noexcept {
        // get smallest value
        return numeric_limits<_Rep>::lowest();
    }

    _NODISCARD static constexpr _Rep(max)() noexcept {
        // get largest value
        return (numeric_limits<_Rep>::max)();
    }
};
```

I've seen the same construct in `numeric_limits`:

```cpp
    _NODISCARD static constexpr _Ty(min)() noexcept {
        return _Ty();
    }
    
    _NODISCARD static constexpr _Ty(max)() noexcept {
        return _Ty();
    }
```

More info, just in case it's needed:

- I'm using Microsoft Visual Studio Professional 2022 Preview (64-bit), Version 17.0.0, Preview 1.1.
- My `chrono` file is under Microsoft Visual Studio\2022\Preview\VC\Tools\MSVC\14.29.30130\include.

And a little online example I've been playing with: https://godbolt.org/z/E5nW7x8vW

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its to defeat macro expansion; the Windows headers used to define macros named `min` and `max`.

Comment: @MarshalClow Ah, OK, thanks. It makes totally sense. Do you know if it is said somewhere that we could use `<RETURN TYPE>(<FUNCTION NAME>)` as an alternative syntax to `<RETURN TYPE> <FUNCTION_NAME>`?

Comment: There's a good example in this answer (https://stackoverflow.com/a/650711/260313), and a good explanation from Johannes Schaub in a comment to that answer. Function-like macros need `(` as next token to the function name for a successful replacement. What I don't understand yet is wy `RETURN TYPE(<FUNCTION NAME>)` is a valid syntax.